# A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)

Tags: java

I like how Java has a Map where you can define the types of each entry in the map, for example `<String, Integer>`.

What I'm looking for is a type of collection where each element in the collection is a pair of values.  Each value in the pair can have its own type (like the String and Integer example above), which is defined at declaration time.

The collection will maintain its given order and will not treat one of the values as a unique key (as in a map).

Essentially I want to be able to define an ARRAY of type `<String,Integer>` or any other 2 types.

I realize that I can make a class with nothing but the 2 variables in it, but that seems overly verbose.

I also realize that I could use a 2D array, but because of the different types I need to use, I'd have to make them arrays of OBJECT, and then I'd have to cast all the time.

I only need to store pairs in the collection, so I only need two values per entry.  Does something like this exist without going the class route?  Thanks!

Comment: i wonder Guava might have a class for this also.

Comment: Guava is pretty anti-`Pair`, and the folks at Google have gone so far as to create a much better alternative - [Auto/Value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value). It lets you easily create *well-typed* value type classes, with proper equals/hashCode semantics. You'll never need a `Pair` type again!

Comment: I would have loved for the answers to go a little further and went into the subject of generic n-tuples, not just pairs, but tuples of arity n.

Comment: As it turns out, java now has a much better alternative to n-tuples: records. I'd argue that they generate less boilerplate than tuples (no generic type declarations to propagate everywhere), only take one line to define and carry a lot more contextual meaning than `Quadruplet<String, int, long, String>`.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

The Pair class is one of those "gimme" generics examples that is easy enough to write on your own. For example, off the top of my head:

```
public class Pair<L,R> {

  private final L left;
  private final R right;

  public Pair(L left, R right) {
    assert left != null;
    assert right != null;

    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  public L getLeft() { return left; }
  public R getRight() { return right; }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() { return left.hashCode() ^ right.hashCode(); }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
    Pair pairo = (Pair) o;
    return this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft()) &&
           this.right.equals(pairo.getRight());
  }

}
```

And yes, this exists in multiple places on the Net, with varying degrees of completeness and feature.  (My example above is intended to be immutable.)

Comment: I like this, but what do you think about making the left and right fields public?  It's pretty clear that the Pair class is never going to have any logic associated and all clients will need access to 'left' and 'right,' so why not make it easy?

Comment: That would kill the immutability of it. This implementation is inherently thread safe at the moment.

Comment: Um...no it wouldn't.  The fields are marked as final, so they can't be reassigned.  And it's not threadsafe because 'left' and 'right' could be mutable.  Unless getLeft()/getRight() returned defensive copies (useless in this case), I don't see what the big deal is.

Comment: I agree with Outlaw.  Plus, it simplifies the idiom for Pair access; Pair is essentially a throwaway placeholder class anyway.  The only reason I might NOT do it is if I planned to extend Pair and override left/right access behavior somehow.

Comment: Meanwhile, to be fair, the Pair code above is threadsafe with respect to itself; that is, it introduces no additional danger that wasn't already innate to the safety of the contained objects.  :-)

Comment: ...oh fargle, scratch that.  It -does- introduce safety problems in the hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: This is quite useful, thanks for it :) btw, it has a little syntax error on the constructor. It should be "public Pair(L left, R right)" instead of "public Pair<L,R>(L left, R right)"

Comment: Note that hashCode() as-is does gives the same value if left and right are swapped. Perhaps:
`long l = left.hashCode() * 2654435761L;`
`return (int)l + (int)(l >>> 32) + right.hashCode();`

Comment: This is nice implementation, but comparing with C++ STL, one feature that is lack of is relational comparison, so it would be nice to have this class implement `Comparable`, and the method `compareTo` would perform a lexicographical comparison on the sequence formed by members first and second.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, rolling out a simple pair class yields a syntax error, a subpar hashCode method, null pointer exceptions, no compareTo method, design questions ... and people still advocate rolling out this class while it exists in Apache commons. Please, just copy the code if you don't want to include the JAR but stop reinventing the wheel!

Comment: What do you mean "easy enough to write on your own"? That's *terrible* software engineering.  Are the N^2 adapter classes to convert between MyPair and SomeoneElsesPair also considered easy enough to write on one's own?

Comment: This `equals()` method is sucseptible to `NullPointerException` if `left` or `right` are `null`. Use `Objects.equals(this.left, pairo.getLeft())` (the same for right) to avoid this.

Comment: The NPE susceptibility was already noted earlier.

Folks, this was never meant to be the One True Pair implementation, and remember, I scribbled it down off the top of my head, without even giving it to a compiler; any syntax errors in it could be easily ironed out. It's as easy to put in as it is to take back out and replace with a third-party alternative if you prefer.

Given how often I've had to go hunting for pre-existing code online that did what I wanted, found it wanting, and had to write my own anyway, yes, this *is* good software engineering when you're trying to get something done.

Comment: I would really use the solution AbstractMap.SimpleEntry (see below answer from JavaHelp4U). No need to implement your own class.

Comment: The question clearly stated "Does something like this exist without going the class route?", but you actually answered going the class route!

Comment: This solution looks remarkably similar to the "Dimension" class implemented on the Selenium library: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Dimension.html

Comment: @PaulBrinkley this will introduce an unchecked cast. Use new Pair<>(someInteger, someString) instead to infer the type, or even explicitly mention it using new Pair<Integer, String>.

Answer (score 355):

### [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)

Easy you are looking for this:

```
java.util.List<java.util.Map.Entry<String,Integer>> pairList= new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

How can you fill it?

```
java.util.Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair1=new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Not Unique key1",1);
java.util.Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair2=new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Not Unique key2",2);
pairList.add(pair1);
pairList.add(pair2);
```

This simplifies to:

```
Entry<String,Integer> pair1=new SimpleEntry<>("Not Unique key1",1);
Entry<String,Integer> pair2=new SimpleEntry<>("Not Unique key2",2);
pairList.add(pair1);
pairList.add(pair2);
```

And, with the help of a `createEntry` method, can further reduce the verbosity to:

```
pairList.add(createEntry("Not Unique key1", 1));
pairList.add(createEntry("Not Unique key2", 2));
```

Since `ArrayList` isn't final, it can be subclassed to expose an `of` method (and the aforementioned `createEntry` method), resulting in the syntactically terse:

```
TupleList<java.util.Map.Entry<String,Integer>> pair = new TupleList<>();
pair.of("Not Unique key1", 1);
pair.of("Not Unique key2", 2);
```

Comment: FYI: That suggested `SimpleEntry` has a sibling class omitting `setValue` method to be immutable. Thus the name [`SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html).

Comment: This is better than self-implementation. The fact that it's easy to implement is not an excuse for implementing it each time.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "standard." `Entry` is meant to be a key-value pair, and it's fine for that. But it has weaknesses as a true tuple. For example the `hashcode` implementation in `SimpleEntry` just xors the codes of the elements, so `<a,b>` hashes to the same value as `<b,a>`.  Tuple implementations often sort lexicographically, but `SimpleEntry`  doesn't implement `Comparable`. So be careful out there...

Comment: Thanks to @Gene for raising the hashcode issue, which came as a surprise to me. The use of XOR also means a bunch of other collisions, including that all pairs where key == value will produce the same (zero) hashcode.

Comment: Why would XORing even be considered a viable option here? Wouldn't even calculating + be more suited for this purpose?

Answer (score 259):

## Java 9+

In Java 9, you can simply write: [`Map.entry(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-)
to create an immutable pair.

**Note:** this method does not allow keys or values to be null. If you want to allow null values, for example, you'd want to change this to: `Map.entry(key, Optional.ofNullable(value))`.

---

## Java 8+

In Java 8, you can use the more general-purpose [`javafx.util.Pair`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) to create an immutable, serializable pair. This class *does* allow null keys and null values. (In Java 9, this class is included in the `javafx.base` module). **EDIT: As of Java 11, JavaFX has been decoupled from the JDK, so you'd need the additional maven artifact org.openjfx:javafx-base.**

---

## Java 6+

In Java 6 and up, you can use the more verbose [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) for an immutable pair, or [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) for a pair whose value can be changed. These classes also allow null keys and null values, and are serializable.

---

## Android

If you're writing for Android, just use [`Pair.create(key, value)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html#create(A,%20B)) to create an immutable pair.

---

## Apache Commons

[`Apache Commons Lang`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) provides the helpful [`Pair.of(key, value)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html#of-L-R-) to create an immutable, comparable, serializable pair.

---

## Eclipse Collections

If you're using pairs that contain primitives, [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) provides some very efficient primitive pair classes that will avoid all the inefficient auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

For instance, you could use [`PrimitiveTuples.pair(int, int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/primitive/PrimitiveTuples.html#pair-int-int-) to create an [`IntIntPair`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/tuple/primitive/IntIntPair.html), or [`PrimitiveTuples.pair(float, long)`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/primitive/PrimitiveTuples.html#pair-float-long-) to create a [`FloatLongPair`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/tuple/primitive/FloatLongPair.html).

---

## Hand-rolled implementations

As of Java 16, [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) have come out of preview status, so you can now do:

```
public record Pair<K, V>(K key, V value) {
    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> of(K key, V value) {
        return new Pair<>(key, value);
    }
}
```

The above implementation will have a big advantage in the future, as it'll allow you to do [record deconstruction](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/405#Deconstruction-patterns).

Prior to Java 16, you can achieve the same semantics with [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/):

```
@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
public class Pair<K, V> {
    K key;
    V value;
}
```

or, with the following verbosity (which, unlike the class listed in the accepted answer, guards against NullPointerExceptions, and has a robust `hashCode()` implementation identical to that of Records<sup>1</sup>):

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Pair<K, V> {

    public final K key;
    public final V value;

    private Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> of(K key, V value) {
        return new Pair<>(key, value);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Pair && Objects.equals(key, ((Pair<?,?>)o).key) && Objects.equals(value, ((Pair<?,?>)o).value);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * Objects.hashCode(key) + Objects.hashCode(value);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Tested on OpenJDK 17

Comment: JavaFX however is desktop-only, adding an unnecessary dependency for non-desktop environments (e.g. servers).

Comment: Eclipse Collections also has a `Pair` interface for objects, which can be instantiated by calling `Tuples.pair(object1, object2)`.  http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/tuple/Pair.html

Comment: Hi @Hans I am using a list `List<Pair<Integer, String> listOfTuple`. How do I use `listOfTuple.add()`? If I'll do - `listOfTuple.add(Pair<someInteger, someString>);`, this will not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the android version is not available in unit test, which makes it not really useful...

Comment: Best answer. It's a pity that the JDK doesn't include classes like `Pair` or `Tuple`, given that the language itself doesn't allow these constructions. Maybe the JDK authors don't want people to use Tuples just to avoid writing more meaningful classes.

Comment: If you use records, why not use specific records and give them a name? It makes your code much more readable: `public record StreetAddress(String street, int number) {}`?

Answer (score 74):

## `Map.Entry`

These built-in classes are an option, too. Both implement the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface.

- [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)
- [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

[image: UML diagram of Map.Entry interface with pair of implementing classes]

Answer (score 33):

Apache common lang3 has Pair class and few other libraries mentioned in this thread [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java/156685#156685)

Example matching the requirement from your original question:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> myPairs = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
myPairs.add(Pair.of("val1", 11));
myPairs.add(Pair.of("val2", 17));

//...

for(Pair<String, Integer> pair : myPairs) {
  //following two lines are equivalent... whichever is easier for you...
  System.out.println(pair.getLeft() + ": " + pair.getRight());
  System.out.println(pair.getKey() + ": " + pair.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest option if Apache Commons is available.

Answer (score 19):

To anyone developing for Android, you can use [android.util.Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html). :)

Answer (score 16):

What about "Apache Commons Lang 3" `Pair` class and the relative subclasses ?

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
    ...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Pair<String, Integer>[] arr = new ImmutablePair[]{
            ImmutablePair.of("A", 1),
            ImmutablePair.of("B", 2)};

    // both access the 'left' part
    String key = arr[0].getKey();
    String left = arr[0].getLeft();

    // both access the 'right' part
    Integer value = arr[0].getValue();
    Integer right = arr[0].getRight();
```

`ImmutablePair` is a specific subclass that does not allow the values in the pair to be modified, but there are others implementations with different semantic. These are the Maven coordinates, if you need them.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

**Java 14+ edition**

You can create a `record` which implements `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` out of the box. Interfaces like `Comparable` could also be implemented, if needed.

```
record Pair<A, B>(A first, B second) {}
```

Records are immutable.

Answer (score 10):

You could write a generic Pair<A, B> class and use this in an array or list.  Yes, you have to write a class, but you can reuse the same class for all types, so you only have to do it once.

Comment: I'd love to see an example of that!

Comment: Dan, the bad thing about that is that it is not possible to accept e.g. only Pair<String,Integer>s because of type erasure, no?

But so is Java...

Comment: Interesting, Johannes.  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: I don't think this will work for plain arrays, but it definitely will work for other Collections.

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer: Good point, you can use it with arrays, but it's ugly as you have to use a hack to create generic arrays.

Comment: @Johannes: Erasure is no more of a problem here than it is anywhere else.  If you declare a field as Pair<String, Integer>, all usages will be checked at compile time.  As with other collections, you can do unsafe things, but they will trigger compiler warnings.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on the other answers a generic immutable Pair should have a static method to avoid cluttering your code with the call to the constructor:

```
class Pair<L,R> {
      final L left;
      final R right;

      public Pair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
      }

      static <L,R> Pair<L,R> of(L left, R right){
          return new Pair<L,R>(left, right);
      }
}
```

if you name the static method "of" or "pairOf" the code becomes fluent as you can write either:

```
    list.add(Pair.of(x,y)); // my preference
    list.add(pairOf(x,y)); // use with import static x.y.Pair.pairOf
```

its a real shame that the core java libraries are so sparse on such things that you have to use commons-lang or other 3rd parties to do such basic stuff. yet another reason to upgrade to scala...

Answer (score 6):

The preferred solution as you've described it is a List of Pairs (i.e. List).

To accomplish this you would create a Pair class for use in your collection. This is a useful utility class to add to your code base.

The closest class in the Sun JDK providing functionality similar to a typical Pair class is AbstractMap.SimpleEntry. You could use this class rather than creating your own Pair class, though you would have to live with some awkward restrictions and I think most people would frown on this as not really the intended role of SimpleEntry. For example SimpleEntry has no "setKey()" method and no default constructor, so you may find it too limiting.

Bear in mind that Collections are designed to contain elements of a single type. Related utility interfaces such as Map are not actually Collections (i.e. Map does not implement the Collection interface). A Pair would not implement the Collection interface either but is obviously a useful class in building larger data structures.

Comment: I find this solution way better than the "winning" one with the generic Pair<K, V>. It does everything requested and comes out of the box. I use this one for my implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Spring has a [`Pair<S,T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Pair.html) type in the Data Utils package [`org.springframework.data.util`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/package-summary.html)

```
Pair<String,Integer> pair = Pair.of("Test", 123);
System.out.println(pair.getFirst());
System.out.println(pair.getSecond());
```

Answer (score 4):

I was going to ask if you would not want to just use a `List<Pair<T, U>>`? but then, of course, the JDK doesn't have a Pair<> class.  But a quick Google found one on both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Generic_class_definitions), and [forums.sun.com](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5132045).  Cheers

Answer (score 4):

This is based on JavaHelp4u 's code.

Less verbose and shows how to do in one line and how to loop over things.

```
//======>  Imports
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

//======>  Single Entry
SimpleEntry<String, String> myEntry = new SimpleEntry<String, String>("ID", "Text");
System.out.println("key: " + myEntry.getKey() + "    value:" + myEntry.getValue());
System.out.println();

//======>  List of Entries
List<Entry<String,String>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();

//-- Specify manually
Entry<String,String> firstButton = new SimpleEntry<String, String>("Red ", "Way out");
pairList.add(firstButton);

//-- one liner:
pairList.add(new SimpleEntry<String,String>("Gray", "Alternate route"));  //Ananomous add.

//-- Iterate over Entry array:
for (Entry<String, String> entr : pairList) {
    System.out.println("Button: " + entr.getKey() + "    Label: " + entr.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I mean, even though there is no `Pair` class in Java there is something pretty simmilar: `Map.Entry`

[Map.Entry Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

This is (simplifying quite a bit) what `HashMap` , or actually any `Map` stores.

You can create an instance of `Map` store your values in it and get the entry set. You will end up with a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` which effectively is what you want.

So:

```
public static void main(String []args)
{    
    HashMap<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    values.put("A", 235);//your custom data, the types may be different
    //more data insertions....
    Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = values.entrySet();//your list 
    //do as you may with it
}
```

Comment: This option has the problem of the unique keys. Let's say you have attributes of persons (e.g. {(person1, "blue-eyed"), (person1, "red-haired", (person2, "shortsighted"), (person2, "quick-thinker")}) you would not be able to store them as pairs in a map, since each person is the key to the map and would only allow one attribute per person.

Answer (score 3):

**Apache Crunch** also has a `Pair` class:
http://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.5.0/org/apache/crunch/Pair.html

Comment: Apache Crunch is retired as a project. And besides that it wouldn't be a good idea to pull in a big framework just to have a simple type like this.

Answer (score 3):

just create a class like

```
class Tuples 
{ 
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

then create List of this objects of Tuples

```
List<Tuples> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

so you can also implement other new data structures in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In project Reactor (io.projectreactor:reactor-core) there is advanced support for n-Tuples:

```
Tuple2<String, Integer> t = Tuples.of("string", 1)
```

There you can get `t.getT1(), t.getT2(), ...` Especially with Stream or Flux you can even map the tuple elements:

```
Stream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> s;
s.map(t -> t.mapT2(i -> i + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing on my mind when talking about key/value pairs is the [Properties Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) where you can save and load items to a stream/file.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse existing `Pair` or any such class from "God knows how many libraries already provide such classes". And If you do not want anything from [Hans Brende's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615100/2266682) then I don't see any reason for not using 2D `Array` or `List` of `Object Arrays/ArrayLists used as Pairs/Tuples`. The reason for not using `Array`, you mentioned:

> I also realize that I could use a 2D array, but because of the different types I need to use, I'd have to make them arrays of OBJECT, and then I'd have to cast all the time.

Even if you use `Pair` class from the ***Accepted Answer***, you'll still have to cast the key and value objects. Since you want to store objects of all the types in there. In other words `List<Pair> pairs` is no different from `List<Pair<? extends Object>> pairs` which in turn is no different from `Object[][2]` or `List<Object[]>` or `List<List<Object>>`. **Because if you write the following code**:

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

// logic for populating pairs into list goes here

// then after sometime you need an element
Pair p = pairs.get(whateverIndex);

Object key = p.getKey(); // We don't know type of key, right?
Object value = p.getValue(); // We don't know the exact type here as well

// All sorts of type guessing statemntes go here
GuessedTypeOfKey finallyMyKey = (GuessedTypeOfKey) key;
GuessedTypeOfValue finallyMyValue = (GuessedTypeOfValue) value;
```

**You still have to do the type casting. So I don't find any other reason to not use 2d `Object array` or `List of Object Arrays/ArrayLists` used as `Pairs/Tuples` . Following is code using List and arrays**

```
List<Object[]> simplePairs = new ArrayList<>();

// Add values to pairs
simplePairs.add(new Object[]{1,"One"});
simplePairs.add(new Object[]{"Another Key of Different Type","Value"});
simplePairs.add(new Object[]{"Another Key of Different Type",new AnotherType("Another Value Type")});

// get values
Object[] pair = simplePairs.get(whateverIndex);
Object key = pair[0];
Object value = pair[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `List` of some kind of object. I personally do not like using generic `Pair` classes. They have too many disadvantages:

- They are not very expressive. They provide no contextual information besides their type arguments.
- They prevent you from using primitive types
- You can't apply any constraints on keys or values (besides their
  type, of course).
- They force you to carry the verbose type parameter declaration in many places (though this is somewhat mitigated by `var` and `<>`)

I prefer using ad-hoc classes.  While a few years ago, this came with annoying boilerplate, this is no longer the case.

Here is a couple of alternatives that makes the declaration of the class really easy:

### Java 14 and above: use a record class

```
record TypedCount(String type, int count) {}
```

There, that's it. You get `toString()` and `equals()` for free

### Before Java 14: use lombok's `@Value` annotation

```
@Value
class TypedCount {
    String type;
    int count;
}
```

That's also it. Lombok automatically makes the fields `private final`, constructors, getters, `toString()` and `equals()`.

While this requires you to add lombok as a dependency, this is only a compile-time dependency that generates the code for you. The lombok library does not need to be in your classpath at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

What about com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair?

Comment: This type is in tools.jar - part of the "Sun" implementation of the javac compiler. It is only distributed as part of the JDK, may not be present in other vendors implementations and is unlikely to be part of the public API.