# How to compare lists in java with a method other than .equals()

Tags: java, list, equals

I want to compare two lists of objects. I want a method that will return a collection of the equal objects (intersections) of the lists. However, the type of object in these lists uses a method other than .equals() to be compared (.isSimilar). Is there a streamlined and efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Streamlined yes, you write a method and you make it return what you said, et voila.

Comment: What I would do is implement a custom [retainAll][1] method that uses a custom comparator. 

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Answer (score 4):

The built-in methods all use the standard `equals` method to see if two objects are equal; none will use your custom `isSimilar` method.

Luckily it's easy to program the logic for computing the intersection yourself: go through the elements in the first list, and add it to the intersection if it exists in the second list.

```
List<YourObject> intersection = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
for (YourObject a: list1) for (YourObject b: list2) {
    if (a.isSimilarTo(b)) {
        intersection.add(a);
        break;
    }
}
```

Computational complexity: if first list has n items and second list has m items this algorithm makes potentially O(nm) comparisons. If the lists were sorted or if a different data structure could be used (for example a hash table) the complexity could be reduced to O(n+m).

On the other hand, you can create a wrapper class for your objects and that uses the isSimilar method for equality:

```
final class YourObjectWrapper {
    YourObject value;
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof YourObjectWrapper
                   ? value.isSimilarTo(((YourObjectWrapper) o).value) 
                   : false;
    }
    // don't forget to override hashCode
}
```

If you fill your lists with these wrapper objects you can use built-in methods like `retainAll`.

Comment: The issue with this is the lists will end up being quite large, and it ends up being incredibly lag-inducing.

Comment: Either way you'll always have to loop over every element in one list to compare it with every element in the other list. Whether you do this yourself or a built-in method does it: it has to be done. If you could sort it on similarity or something, you could cut it off pre-emptively but this doesn't seem very likely from what I can tell.

Comment: If you can use a hash table for the second list you don't have to compare every pair of items; you can find if an item exists in a hash table in constant time so the intersection can be built in O(n) time. But transforming the second list into a hash table takes O(m) time, so in total you get O(n+m). I don't think you can do better than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the `isSimilar()` issue either by setting `equals()` to call `isSimilar()` in the item class or by using a class that extends one of List implementations and there you should override the method `contains()` to use `isSimilar()` instead of `equals().`

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid changing the semantics of `equals()`, both for lists and for items...

Anyway, I think you might like to use [Guava's functional idioms](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained):

- Define an `Iterable<Pair<T,T>>`-implementing class constructed with a pair of `List<T>`, with the iteration proceeding from one pair of corresponding elements to the next.
- Create a predicate on pairs which uses `isSimilar()` on the first and second pair.
- Use `Iterables.any(theIterableYouCreated, thePredicateYouCreated)`.

Don't have a pair class already? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6044923/1593077). Also, you'll need to handle the case of different lengths, which you can do before constructing the iterator; or you could do it some other way.

Comment: If you already have a Predicate that checks for equality, this approach would save you a little trouble. But when you consider that you still have to write an Iterable that builds Pairs and checks for edge cases, it's not much better than writing the whole things yourself. If you don't already have a Predicate, it becomes an exercise in wrapping your code in Google's API for the sake of saving yourself a for-loop and if-statement. Just a heads up for anyone who isn't already heavily vested in Guava.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient streamlined way to do this is to write you own method for this. That said, this would be a simple method, where you compare the two objects and if they are equal you add them to a list, or other collection.

Answer (score 0):

No solution present. I take it that you cannot sort the lists (similarity). Hence you need to compare every element from one list with all of the others to see whether no similar is found, in order to reject it. N x M, quadratic complexity.