# How to Store a One to One Relationship in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, relationship, one-to-one

I am wondering if there is a data structure that can store one to one relationship in Java.

For example, for mapping the month of the year with its number and vice versa.

I know I can use two `HashMaps`, but I want to know if there is another data structure that also checks the value when I put a new pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none in standard Java though. You can however use [Guava's `BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) if you can use a 3rd party library.

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
>   containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values.

Comment: I would add that if he can't use a 3rd party library, it's fairly simple to create a wrapper object that behaves like a BiMap by storing two maps in an object, the first that uses key --> value, the second that uses value --> key.  You'd have to add some logic to make sure `put` operations behave correctly, but not terribly difficult to do

Comment: And if I am not wrong, the complexity is still O(1), right? Two lookups, and two comparisons for put, and one lookup for get.

Comment: @AfshinMoazami. Yes, `put` and `get` are still constant time operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data structure for that, but I think you can use a parameterized Pair for this task. This class is so popular that you will it on the internet.

Here is one on SO:
[Generic pair class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044923/generic-pair-class)

Answer (score 0):

Needed a solution to this recently, but didn't want to rely on a plugin....so I extended the base Java Class.  This implementation does not allow `null` values.

```
public class OneToOneMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    public OneToOneMap() {
        super();
    }
    public OneToOneMap(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }
    public OneToOneMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }
    public OneToOneMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        super(m);
        dedup();
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m){
        super.putAll(m);
        dedup();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if( key == null || value == null ) return null;
        removeValue(value);
        return super.put(key,value);
    }

    public K getKey( V value ){
        if( value == null || this.size() == 0 ) return null;
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            if( value.equals(get(key) )) return key;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public boolean hasValue( V value ){
        return getKey(value) != null;
    }
    public boolean hasKey( K key ){
        return get(key) != null;
    }

    public void removeValue( V remove ){
        V value;
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            value = get(key);
            if( value == null || key == null || value.equals(remove)) remove(key);
        }        
    }
    //can be used when a new map is assigned to clean it up
    public void dedup(){
        V value;
        Set<V> values = new HashSet<>();
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            value = get(key);
            if( value == null || key == null || values.contains(value) ) remove(key);
            else values.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```