# return a double and int value from function in java

Tags: java

I want to receive two values from a function in GUI one of that is double and other is of type int.
in my check profit interface i want to have value of two variables that is profitAmount and quantityItemSold to be updated by values calculated in class register.java as i was implementing java objects are pass by reference so i made objects of Double profitAmount and Integer quantityItemSold and passed them into function of gui by respective objects.

List of Classes

//checkProfitOfItemInterface.java

```
if(checkButton==btnNewButtonCheck){

    shop.checkProfit(jTextFieldItemCode.getText(),jTextFieldDate.getText(),profitAmount,quantityOfItemSold);
    System.out.println("Quantity:  "+ quantityOfItemSold + "  Profit: "+ profitAmount); 
    //model.addRow(arg0);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"s","s",quantityOfItemSold,"s",profitAmount});
}
```

//shop.java

```
public void checkProfit(String itemCode, String date, Double profitAmount, Integer quantityOfItemSold) {

    int itemCodeInt = Integer.parseInt(itemCode);
    ItemDescription objItemDescription =itemDescriptions.get(itemCodeInt); 
    register.checkProfit(itemCode,objItemDescription,date,profitAmount,quantityOfItemSold);

}
```

//register.java

```
public void checkProfit(String itemCode, ItemDescription itemDescription, String enteredDate,Double profitAmount, Integer quantityOfItemSold1) {

    int itemCodeInt = Integer.parseInt(itemCode);

    //GET no of sales being saved in register
    int noOfSales = sales.size();
    double salePrice=0;
    double purchasePrice =0;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date saleDate=null;
    Date enteredDateToCheckProfitFrom = null;


    int quantityOfItemSold =0;


    for(int i=0;i<noOfSales;i++){

        Sale objSale= sales.get(i);

        //get date of required sale 
        saleDate =  objSale.getDateOfSale();
        try {
            enteredDateToCheckProfitFrom = sdf.parse(enteredDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //compared entered date to required sale date
        int value = enteredDateToCheckProfitFrom.compareTo(saleDate);

        if(value >= 0){

        quantityOfItemSold += objSale.getCountOfItemsInSale(itemCodeInt);
        }

    }

    salePrice =itemDescription.getSalePrice();
    purchasePrice = itemDescription.getPurchasePrice();

    double profitOnSaleOfOneItem = salePrice - purchasePrice;

    double totalProfit = quantityOfItemSold * profitOnSaleOfOneItem;

    profitAmount = totalProfit;
    quantityOfItemSold1 = quantityOfItemSold;

    System.out.println("Quantity:  "+ quantityOfItemSold1 + "  Profit: "+ profitAmount);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use a Pair class to hold a Double and Integer objects.

[Generic pair class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044923/generic-pair-class)

Comment: Isn't it violation of OOAD concepts as just keeping a class for recieving just two variables. Otherwise that class remains idle.

Comment: You can't do better in java. Just consider this as an analogue of tuple.

Comment: @AbdullahJahangirAbbasi - No it isn't.  There is not OOAD that says that classes need to be complicated, used for lots of things, etc.