# Java: How can I use an integer pair in Java?

Tags: java, treemap

I have to take the input of some integer pairs. After that sort them and I've to do some arithmetic operation with the pair.
I used `TreeMap` as it allows sorting too but it fails when I have the duplicate key.
So, what collection/method should I use in my program? Please suggest.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> h = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    String ll[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
    h.put(Integer.parseInt(ll[0]), Integer.parseInt(ll[1]));            
}
```

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044923/generic-pair-class) SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `TreeMap`, you can define your own pair class, put the objects in an `ArrayList` and sort the elements based on the key.

```
class Pair{
 final int first;
 final int second;
 .... constructor, getters 
}
```

And then sort it using `Collections.sort`

```
Collections.sort(pairs, Pair::getFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not implementing your own class?

Such as

```
class Pair implements Comparable {
    int a, b;
    // Implement operations you want, compareTo() method
}
```

The you can store these Pair objects in `ArrayList<Pair>` and use `Collections.sort()` method to sort the data way you want.