# How can I create a matrix of BigInteger whose dimension is a BigInteger?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, biginteger

I want to create a matrix of BigInteger whose dimension is a BigInteger too, but this create a error and I don't know why

```
BigInteger[][] matA;
BigInteger n;
System.out.println("Ingrese N: ");
n = sc.nextBigInteger();
matA = new BigInteger[n][n];
```

This is the error of java:

> incompatible types: BigInteger cannot be converted to int

Comment: The max size of an array is 2^32-1 so it's not possible

Comment: Arrays are indexed by `int`. Not `BigInteger`. And arrays (per the Java specification) have a **fixed** `length` field (which is also of type `int`). If this is *intended* to be sparse, you could probably write something based on a [`Map<Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger>, BigInteger>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045145/2970947).

Comment: this is because the array index expects an int argument, not a BigInteger