# Java generic Pair class printing our weird characters

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertion

I am using a generic Pair class which I took from here [Generic pair class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044923/generic-pair-class)

Now I need to write unit tests for each method of the class. For these tests I wrote for example:

```
Pair p1 = new Pair("a",2);
Assert.assertEquals("(a,2)", p1.toString());`
```

My tests are failing with the following message. Could anyone help me how to overcome this issue for both the unit test and the program itself? I am very new at Java, and I couldn't find anything to solve this problem.

```
expected:<[(1,2)]> but was:<[Pair@58d25a40]>
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[(1,2)]> but was:<[Pair@58d25a40]>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to override `toString` in your class.

Comment: Do you mean adding a new toString() method?

Comment: Additionally, if it is a generic pair class, you're missing the type variables. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176

Comment: the elements can be string or int. I thought if I don't specify anything, they could be either. What would you suggest in that case?

Comment: `Pair<String, Integer> p1 = new Pair<>("a", 2);`.