# Using pairs in Java for database names and values

Tags: java

I am trying to create a generic database function to populate default values into a table on creation if need be. I have a class which will create pairs, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples) but don't quite understand how it works! :(

I believe I would create something like this for the pairs:

```
public class DBColumnValuePair<T, V>
{
    private final T column;
    private final V value;

public DBColumnValuePair(T column, V value)
{
    this.column = column;
    this.value = value;
}

public T getColumn()
{
    return column;
}

public V getValue()
{
    return value;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{

    return this.column.hashCode() ^ this.value.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof DBColumnValuePair))
    {
        return false;
    }
    DBColumnValuePair dbCVPObject = (DBColumnValuePair) o;
    return this.column.equals(dbCVPObject.getColumn())
            && this.value.equals(dbCVPObject.getValue());
}
 }
```

Then populate an array with these pairs? Then send this to the method I want to handle the default values.

So my question is how do i populate the pairs in the first place? and would an array of pairs be the way to send them to the handler method?

Hope you can help :)

Comment: Well no sooner had I posted than I realised that it would be quite simple, it's amazing what taking a break and grabbing a beer does!!

   `code DBColumnValuePair<String, Integer> test = new DBColumnValuePair<String, Integer>("Ian", 1);
  test2 = new DBColumnValuePair[3];
  test2[0] = test; 
  Log.e("Ian", "T value: " + test2[0].getColumn());
  Log.e("Ian", "V value: " + test2[0].getValue()); `

Comment: If all you are interested is key value pairs, why don't you just use a `HashMap`?

Comment: LOL, Because I have spent a long time in front of my computer so i thought i'd re-invent the wheel!! Hashmaps would work a treat! thanks :)

Comment: If you've solved your problem, then you should post your solution as an answer, and then accept it. :-)

Comment: It appears I cannot for another few hours, I tried to in the above comment but it came out as a garbled mess :)!! will try again later. Huh unless i edit the question :)

Comment: A hashmap is not the same as an array of pairs. A map is a `set` of `A` mapped to `B`, whereas an array of pairs is akin to two arrays of the same size `A` + `B`.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question. You might want to post your answer as a real answer (which you can accept yourself later).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Well I figured it out, even though as ring bearer pointed out I could just use a HashMap!

What I did follows:

```
DBColumnValuePair<String, Integer> test = new DBColumnValuePair<String, Integer>("Ian", 1);
test2 = new DBColumnValuePair[3];
test2[0] = test;
Log.e("Ian", "T value: " + test2[0].getColumn());
Log.e("Ian", "V value: " + test2[0].getValue());
```

Comment: [Answered in a question edit. Moved to Community Wiki.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)