# how to shuffle two list in the same fashion in java?

Tags: java

I want to shuffle two list in the same fashion. Suppose I have two lists questions and answers. I want to shuffle them both in the same manner so that the question answer pair remains the same.

Comment: You have questions and answers in separate lists? OMG.

Comment: Why not have a simple `QA` class that combines both the question and the answer?  That way you only need one list.

Comment: Yeah that's a great idea I can use a class.

Answer (score 6):

Java Collections has a (surprisingly) simple solution to this problem: `Collections.shuffle(Collection<?>, Random)` with a `Random` seeded with same seed.

```
    List<Integer> quests = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<Integer> answers = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(quests, new Random(seed));
    Collections.shuffle(answers, new Random(seed));

    System.out.println(quests);
    System.out.println(answers);
```

### Note:

*Extra optimization is dangerous.*
**This DOE NOT WORK:**

```
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Random rnd = new Random(seed);
    Collections.shuffle(quests, rnd);
    Collections.shuffle(answers, rnd);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of two separate lists, you should rather keep your question-answer pairs in either a `Map<YourQuestionType, YourAnswerType>`, or a `List<YourQuestionAnswerPair>`.

For a generic solution to the latter, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples) may also be useful.

Comment: The problem the application runs on a server and every student should get the questions in random order. And the difficulty in using a map is that I cannot shuffle it.

Comment: @dnivra, you can't shuffle the Map directly, but you may extract a list of all its keys to a separate List and shuffle that. If you want to have a different ordering for each user, you need to shallow copy your source collection anyway, be it a List or a Map. So using a Map is actually more effective as you only copy the collection of keys (questions), but not the values (answers).