# Efficient lookup of list of pairs (java)

Tags: java, big-o, performance

I have a data structure that is essentially key-value pairs. However unlike a dictionary I might have duplicate keys, this is legitimate in the system I'm designing. Currently I have a Java class that implements a Pair object (A lot like the example here [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)) which has a left and a right (key and value) I then store these in an ArrayList.

What I want is a means of looking up the keys in a fashion quicker that O(N) as the list can grow quite large.

I have thought about potentially creating an inverted index, however wondered whether there is another way?

To handle reduce of a duplicates I really just want to obtain a list of positions in the list based on the key.

Doesn't have to be in Java - thats just what I'll be implementing in.

Cheers

David

Comment: I forgot to mention that position of the items in the list of pairs is important as this refers to the position of something in another data structure. Does a MultiMap allow for this?

Comment: Answered my own question, a ListMultimap looks best. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you supposed to get if you ask for the value of a key that exists multiple times? Depending on the answer to that question [Apache Commons MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) might solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

I would use a MultiMap e.g. [Guava's MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) or `Map<Key, List<Value>>` or `Map<Key, Set<Value>>`

This allows you to have multiple values for the same key and has an O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that since you're storing key/values, and those keys can be duplicates, you really need a [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) (I've linked to the Guava version, but [others](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) exist).

Alternatively you can implement a map of keys to lists of values. That's a little more laborious but will work in a very similar fashion.