# How to keep the order of elements in hashtable in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, hashtable

I am inserting some values in hashtable. But its 
not keeping the order as i inserted.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SignatureKey.size(); i++) {

               m.put(SignatureKey.elementAt(i), SignatureValue.elementAt(i));
    }
```

please suggest something.

Answer (score 4):

By its nature a hash table should be an unordered collection. If you want to preserve the ordering of your elements, use a different data structure.

Comment: can you please explain which data structure, I can use to preserve the order. I need this for native blackberry development.

Comment: but how can i put keypair values in a vector.

Comment: One way would be to make a keypair class, and have a vector of those. [Take a look at this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples).