# What data structure should I use to store a pair of strings in Java , if my goal is to find unique pairs?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am a beginner in Java. I have some sample data of *nodes*:

```
A -> B

B -> F

C -> R

A -> B

B -> C

R -> C
```

I have already taken out 2 lists: [A,B,C,A,B,R]  and [B,F,R,B,C,C]

However, how should I go about storing the pairs [AB, BF, CR, AB, BC, RC] so that I can find unique pairs? By unique, I mean AB is not equal to BA .

1) So Basically I would like to identify unique pairs.

2) I also want to count the number of times each unique pair has appeared.

**EDITED:**

**3) I am also interested in finding how many different nodes each node connects to.**

**4) And how many different nodes connect to each node**

I am struggling to decide whether I really need to write my own class or is there an easier method?

Comment: Encapsulate it into a `Pair` class and then use a set to count unique and a list to hold all. You'll need `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Comment: Here is a useful resource for implementing your own pair class:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples

Comment: `I also want to count the number of times each unique pair has appeared.` what does it mean? if a pair is unique, it appears only once right?

Comment: This means: if we have 2 pairs (A,B) and (B,A). They are 2 different pairs. However, if we have (A,B) and (A,B), then they are considered as one unique pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtable (datastructure) should work for your requirement. In java, you could consider type `HashMap<String,Integer>`

key is the string pair, Integer is count:

something like:

```
{
"AB":2,
"CR":1,
"BF":1,
...

}
```

The complexity of finding unique pairs would be `O(n)`

**EDIT**

it seems that putting codes here helps to explain the solution:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

//you have two lists with those strings, called list1 and list2.
// list1<String> and list2<String> have same size

String key = null;
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
    key = list1.get(i) + list2.get(i);
    if(map.containsKey(key))
        map.get(key)++;
    else
        map.put(key,1);
}

//now the map has been filled, you can go through the map, 
//and check the value, if value == 1, then the key is unique.
//for those value >1, you know, which string pair is not unique, 
// and how many times it shows.
```

codes were not written in IDE, so there could be typoes.

Comment: This assumes you can concatenate the Strings.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP has already done that, right? If I understood the Q right. let me read it again.

Comment: @Kent OP only mentioned pairs; IMO it's general enough that it shouldn't really matter since the question is about the underlying data structure, not the nature of the data. That the OP is a beginner, however, throws a spanner in the works, so I'm not sure how generalized an answer should be.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if there are two arrays/lists of string, as long as they have same length/size, hashtable works anyway., still `O(n)` `for (int i=0;i<size/length;i++) String k = a[i]+b[i]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answers. Since AB is not equal to BA, I tried to put 2 strings together and then put them into a hashset to obtain set of strings with no duplicates. Is this a feasible method for getting unique pairs??

Answer (score 10):

You can create a custom class to store pairs of strings and then use a `HashMap` to keep track of the count

```
public class StringPair {
   String leftString;
   String rightString;

   //NOTE: override hashcode and equals methods
}
```

And then you can use `HashMap` for keeping tracking of the count:

```
Map<StringPair, Integer> pairCountMap = new HashMap<StringPair, Integer>();

if(pairCountMap.containsKey(aPairObject)) {
   pairCountMap.put(aPairObject, pairCountMap.get(aPairObject)+1);
} else {
   pairCountMap.put(aPairObject, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a class to designate pair:

```
public class Pair{
 String prv;
 String next;
 //override hashcode and equals
}
```

If you use `Set` and fill it in with all pair, you'll end-up having unique pairs:

```
Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();
..
pairs.add(new Pair(prv, next));
int uniquePairs = pairs.size();
```

If you use `TreeSet` and make `Pair` `implement` `Comparable`, you'll have a sorted list of pairs

```
Set<Pair> pairs = new TreeSet<Pair>();
..
System.out.println(pairs);
```

Further, you can use a combination of `List` and `Set` and apply some logic to figure out exact number of duplicates etc, can also explore `removeAll` and `retainAll` for implementing logic.

Also, `Map` doesn't seem to be a fit in your use case since a class can wrap required mapping and list or set will help to apply desired logic over multiple pairs.

To get counts of total number of original pairs:

```
Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();
int count =0;
while(..) { //iterating over list of pairs
    pairs.add(new Pair(prv, next));
    count ++;
   }
int uniquePairs = pairs.size();
int totalPairs = count;
```

Comment: How do you count how many times a pair has occurred? Using a set will only tell you how many unique pairs there are but will not provide the count of the pairs.

Comment: One way is while collecting pairs, I've modified my answer. Using `HashMap` to track count seems to be a hack (which works) but certainly not right use case of a map.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to count how many times a pair occurs. For e.g A->B pair occurs 10 times, B->C occurs only 5 times etc. For this usecase, HashMap is perfect. Why is it a hack? Your solution is counting total pairs not the count of individual pair. Think of 'group by' functionality in a SQL query.