# Send tuples of BigInteger objects across network, and append the binary representation of these to an array in Java

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I've a client and a server and I want to send tuples of BigInteger objects between them, each time appending the binary representation of a tuple to an initially empty array.

This is done in order to implement a security protocol.

I've been searching for good ideas on how to send these BigInteger objects as tuples, so that these tuples are easy to send/receive and append to an array.

Could someone describe how to do this for a rather inexperienced programmer with an interest in cryptography (possibly with examples)?

Answer (score 1):

Tuples does not exist in `Java`, you can create a `Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>` to *simulate* it or [write your own class as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521235/3850595)