# make sure a list has unique values

Tags: java

**How can I get a *collection* of unique pairs of values in Java?**

I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples) and tried the following code from an answer to that posting as a `Pair` class:

```
public class Pair<L,R> {

  private final L left;
  private final R right;

  public Pair(L left, R right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  public L getLeft() { return left; }
  public R getRight() { return right; }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() { return left.hashCode() ^ right.hashCode(); }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
    Pair pairo = (Pair) o;
    return this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft()) &&
           this.right.equals(pairo.getRight());
  }

}
```

But how to I ensure that a collection of `Pair` objects only contains unique combinations of `left`+`right` using the `Pair` class?

Here is my first attempt:

```
            sel_person = this.serviceLayer.findSelPerson(patntId);
            ArrayList<Pair> ps = new ArrayList<Pair>();
            for(int ee=0;ee<sel_person.getRoles().size();ee++){
                Pair p1 = new Pair(sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId1Root(), sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId1Extension());
                ps.add(p1);
                Pair p2 = new Pair(sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId2Root(), sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId2Extension());
                ps.add(p2);
            }
```

My fear is that the `ArrayList` will not care if there are redundant combinations of `left`+`right`.  I wonder if the `hashcode` method will somehow prevent instantiation of `Pair` objects with redundant combinations of `left`+right`, but how can I be sure?  If the above code is correct, then a good answer would simply explain why.  If something else needs to be done, then a good answer would explain what else needs to be done.

Comment: Assuming that `equals` will tell you whether two elements are unique, `HashSet` should do the job.

Comment: You may also want to check whether the parameter `Object o` to the `equals` method is null and return false if it is.

Comment: You also have the possibility of getting a `NullPointerException` with `this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft())` since `this.left` could be `null` (same with right). This will also break the symmetric contract of `equals` since `a.equals(b)` could be `false` while `b.equals(a)` could throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to I ensure that a collection of Pair objects only contains unique combinations of left+right using the Pair class?

A `List` cares not about duplicate elements. An implementation of the `Set` interface (for instance [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) is more appropriate, as a `Set` is defined as a Collection of unique elements (uniqueness as defined by `hashCode` and `equals` of the Objects it contains).

```
Set<Pair> ps = new HashSet<Pair>();
for(int ee=0;ee<sel_person.getRoles().size();ee++){
    Pair p1 = new Pair(sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId1Root(), sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId1Extension());
    ps.add(p1);
    Pair p2 = new Pair(sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId2Root(), sel_person.getRoles().get(ee).getId2Extension());
    ps.add(p2);
}
//now ps has only unique pairs as defined by the Pair class hashcode/equals
```

Answer (score 2):

HashSet does the trick for you

```
ArrayList<Pair> ps = new ArrayList<Pair>();
Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<Pair>(ps);
```

`set` will then contain the unique objects.