# How can I use .doOnNext() with Action2 (RxJava)

Tags: java, rx-java, system.reactive

Observables only emit one object, so `doOnNext()` is always called with an [`Action1`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/functions/Action1.html).  How can I use [`Action2`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/functions/Action2.html) in a similar fashion?

Can I combine 2 observables call an `Action2`?

EDIT: Why would I want to do this? I am working on a checkout app. I have a view that in order to display correctly, it needs two pieces of data (1: tip% and 2: total cost). So if this view could react to an observable sequence as an `Action2`, I would be happy.

EDIT2: Here's a method on the view mentioned previously. If this were an `Action1`, I could easily call it like I do with `.doOnNext()`. Are there operators that can operate similarly to `.doOnNext()` but take in an `Action2` as a parameter? Maybe something like `withLatestFrom()` that takes in an `Action2` instead of a `Func2`?

```
public Action2<Money, List<Integer>> displayGratuityOptions() {
        return (subtotal, gratuityPercents) -> {
            removeAllTabs();
            for (final Integer percent : gratuityPercents) {
                addTab(createTab(subtotal, percent));
            }
            addTab(createCustomGratuityTab());       
        };
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is your use case?

Comment: You need to explain a little more clearly what you're asking.

Comment: You say "Why would I want to do this?" but I don't know what you mean by "this". Can you please explain what you mean by `Action1` and `Action2`? What are their types? What do you mean that an observable can call them? etc, etc, etc...

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess I want to simulate `.withLatestFrom()` but as an `Action2` instead of a `Func2`. I guess this isn't possible?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi - I still don't know what you mean. Can you **explain** what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Operators like `withLatestFrom` are there to combine multiple sequences into a single sequence. I think you will be better placed to work with Rx if you can adopt this way of thinking i.e. single data type sequences.

To this end I would suggest creating a type that has both the data types you want. You can then merge your data and then pass the single value to your `doOnNext` handler*.

This is simple stuff in most languages that Rx is used in (C#, F#, JS, Scala) but in Java, you may have to actually declare/define a type to do this. See - [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)

*Please try to avoid using the `Do` side-effect operators. There is almost always a better way. In you example it looks like you are doing some significant work in that handler (Creating, Adding and Removing tabs which I assume are Visual Controls)