# How to pass null into Pair<String, String> in Java

Tags: java, android, null, keyvaluepair

I'm new to Java. I'm creating an app in android, and I created a method that takes a varargs of `Pair<String, String>`. But I can't seem to pass null in. Is this possible?

Method:

```
makeJson(Pair<String, String>... keyValuePairs) {
...
}
```

Caller:

```
makeJson(Pair.create("reference", null));
```

Comment: Pair is not standard Java class. Please specify library where you get it.

Comment: You can use just 'new Pair<String, String>("reference", null)'

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets android.support.v4.util

Comment: And yes it is possible to write `Pair.create("reference", null)`. What type of error do you have?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin thanks. The IDE doesn't show errors anymore. I will try it out and report back.

Comment: Please follow below link [This link will help you Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)

Comment: @RahulKarande Doubtful.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSpitsin. That worked!

Comment: If anyone in this thread downvoted the question, would you mind sharing why? It's kind of pointless otherwise.

Comment: @user1422348 I prepared and designed an answer for you. Please check it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just ordinary Pair's constructor:

```
new Pair<String, String>("reference", null)
```

And according link to [the source code of Pair.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/util/Pair.java#Pair):

```
public static <A, B> Pair<A, B> create(A a, B b) {
    return new Pair<A, B>(a, b);
}
```

Static method `create` just invokes constructor so it should work with nulls.

Comment: Pair Class from util in spring data does not allow these null values:  private Pair(@NonNull S first, @NonNull T second) {...

Answer (score -1):

Better way to handle this will be to use Optional,

Pair.of(Optional.of(?), Optional.of(Object B))