# Making successive api calls with Retrofit and returning observable

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a retrofit service that contains the following interface

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("/users/me")
    Observable<Account> authenticateUser(@Header("Authorization") String auth);

    @GET("/membership/{userId}")
    SubscriptionStatus getSubscriptionStatus(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

I would like to define a method to make an api call to get the Account which contains the userId, and then use this ID to make a second API call to get The users subscription status. SubscriptionStatus contains a boolean and if its true I would like the method to return Observable.

This is how I have gone about it so far :

```
public Observable<Account> doLogin(ApiService service , String credentials) {

return service.authenticateuser(base64) // gets Account observable 
       .doOnNext(account -> {
            currentAccount = account; // setting the Account Variable
        })
        .flatMap(account -> service.getSubscriptionStatus(account.getUserId())) // get Account Subscription status

        ... //unsure where to go from here I need to check 
           //the subscriptionStatus object and return account           
           //observable if condition is valid
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
return service.authenticateuser(base64) // gets Account observable 
   .doOnNext(account -> {
        currentAccount = account; // setting the Account Variable
    })
    .flatMap(account -> 
         service.getSubscriptionStatus(account.getUserId())
         .filter(status -> status.isActive()) // don't let status pass if not active
         .map(status -> account)  // we actually need the original account
    );
```

In case you need both the account and the status, the last map() should return some [composite type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples) of the two:

```
 .map(status -> new Pair<>(account, status))
```

Comment: Thanks alot this worked, Do you know how I can handle and return errors for each API call?