# Sort list with help of index

Tags: java, java-stream

Can I access the index of the object in the list somehow?

```
myList.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

e.g.:

I'd like odd indices to be displayed first and even indices at the end.

Comment: Sorry I mean list

Comment: `List#indexOf`?

Comment: Where’s the sense in that? The elements of a `List` are already sorted by their position.

Comment: I have a list and would like the list in another order. I would like to access the index of an element in the Comparator

Comment: That still doesn’t explain anything. If you want to have *another* order, you don’t need the *original* position.

Comment: And how do you want to sort all odd/even indices?

Comment: @Holger even if that don't make sense without the context. It is easy to understand that he want to reorder his list using the original index using a modulo to put first the index [0], [2], [4], [6], ... then followed by [1], [3], [5], [7],... (of the original list)

Comment: I want to sort the elements by their corresponding index in the list

Comment: @AxelH: I never encounter the need for that in real life, however, if that’s the OP’s intention, what stops the OP from explaining the actual intention right in the question?

Comment: @Holger I clearly don't see the reason either ;) but I found the last statement quite clear, an example would have been nice though

Comment: @AxelH: I somehow missed that sentence. So the lesson is, the problem statement should come first, before the attempted solution…

Comment: @Holger I could not agree more !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer works, but this works too (as long as there are no duplicates in the list):

```
// a list to test with
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""));

List<String> list2 = list.stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> list.indexOf(x) % 2).thenComparing(x -> list.indexOf(x)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
list2.forEach(System.out::print);
```

This prints odd indices first, then the even indices

```
acegikmoqsuwybdfhjlnprtvxz
```

---

Just to illustrate the point Holger made in his comment.

- The solution in this answer took my machine 75 ms to run.
- The solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757072/7598776) took only 3 ms.
- And Holger's own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757605/7598776) ends up with an astonishing < 0 ms.

Comment: Same as with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757217/2711488), readers should be aware that making two linear searches for each comparison, is horribly inefficient and should never be used in production code.

Comment: Also this will break if there are duplicate entries in the list.

Comment: Have update the answer with the difference in performance of the difference answers and a note with @slim's valid remark

Comment: I still don't get why so many people want to use the stream API for every problem, when the "old" way is clearly better suited for the problem!?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t consider index based reordering operations to be actual *sorting* operations. E.g., no-one would consider implementing an operation like [`Collections.reverse(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) as a sorting operation.

An efficient method for moving elements at odd positions to the front in-place would be

```
public static <T> void oddFirst(List<T> list) {
    final int size = list.size();
    for(int index1=0, index2=list.size()/2|1; index2<size; index1+=2, index2+=2)
        Collections.swap(list, index1, index2);
}
```

Alternatively, you may stream over the indices like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757072/2711488), to generate a new `List`.

Answer (score 2):

A filter may help:

```
List<Integer> listEvenIndicesMembers = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> listOddIndicesMembers = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(n -> n % 2 != 0).mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(listEvenIndicesMembers);
System.out.println(listOddIndicesMembers);
```

> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
>
> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

the problem is now you have 2 lists, appending one after the other will produce the same you want... am still checking the doc maybe I find something more elegant/optimized.

## Edit:

Thanks to @Holger for the neat suggestion:

you can concatenate the streams doing:

```
List<Integer> listOptimal = IntStream
            .concat(IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0),
                    IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(n -> n % 2 != 0))
            .mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(listOptimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think solution of [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757072/4391450) should be fine for you, here's just an alternative (remember, it's just an alternative for the sake of learning, this solution should not be used in 'real life', it's just to show the possibility):

```java
public static void main(String arg[]) {
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H");
  List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);

  list.sort((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(listCopy.indexOf(o2) % 2, listCopy.indexOf(o1) % 2));

  System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output is: `[B, D, F, H, A, C, E, G]`

Comment: You confused the names; you should decide for either, `listCopy` or `list2`. Still, that’s horribly inefficient and should never be used in production code.

Comment: Yes thanks I fixed that, and yes, I know it's a bad solution, just alternative, for the sake of learning :)

Comment: Agree, I don't want to see the result with a 1000+ item list. But I like the idea !

Answer (score 1):

You may use the decorator pattern to store your objects plus extra information for sorting. E.g. if you have a list of strings you want to sort (add getters):

```
class StringWithIndex {
    String text;
    int index;
    int evenIndex;

    StringWithIndex(String text, int index) {
        this.text = text;
        this.index = index;
        this.evenIndex = index % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

And then you can sort such objects instead of strings:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

List<String> sorted = IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new StringWithIndex(strings.get(i), i))
        .sorted(comparingInt(StringWithIndex::getEvenIndex).thenComparingInt(StringWithIndex::getIndex))
        .map(StringWithIndex::getText)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This adds some overhead to create temporary objects and requires another class. But it can prove very useful as the sorting rules become more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is move `List` values around according to their index, then see my other answer.

However, the original wording of your question suggests you want to use `sort()` or `sorted()` with a comparator that takes existing position into account as well as other aspects of the value.

This would also be difficult if you just used `Collections.sort()`, because the `Comparator` used there doesn't have access to the index either.

You could map your `Stream<T>` to a `Stream<Entry<Integer,T>>` and perhaps map it back to `Stream<T>` when you've finished:

(This is `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` -- because it exists in the standard libs -- you could also write your own `Pair` or use one from a 3rd party -- see [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples) )

```
mystream.map(addIndex()).sorted(compareEntry()).map(stripIndex()) ...

private <T> Function<T,Entry<Integer,T>> addIndex() {
    final int[] index = new int[] { 0 };
    return o -> new SimpleEntry(index[0]++, o);    
}

private Comparator<Entry<Integer, T>> compareEntry() {
    return a,b -> {
       // your comparison code here -- you have access to
       // getKey() and getValue() for both parameters
    };
}

private <T> Function<Entry<Integer,T>, T> stripIndex() {
    return e -> e.getValue();
}
```

Note that `addIndex()`, at least, is not parallelisable. I suppose that once all the entries are tagged with indices, downstream from there things could be done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus answer - if all you want to do is create a new List containing the odd entries followed by the even entries, then using `Stream` is adding needless complexity.

```
 for(int i=0; i<inlist.size(); i+=2) {
     outlist.add(inlist.get(i));
 }
 for(int i=1; i<inlist.size(); i+=2) {
     outlist.add(inlist.get(i));
 }
```

There's also a pretty simple algorithm what will re-order the list in-place -- which you can write for yourself. Think about it -- there's a simple function to get the new index from the old index, as long as you know the list length.