# Formatting output for Printing pair in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to check my pair against a unit test but the output from the function returns the pair with pair values separated with "=" instead of ",". I tried type casting and other workarounds but can't figure out whats making this happen.

Function return type :

```
Pair<ArrayList<Pair<Entity, Integer>>, Integer>

ArrayList<Pair<Entity, Integer>> pairMatches = new ArrayList<Pair<Entity, Integer>>();

pairMatches.add(new Pair<>(entities.get(i-1), ped)); // entities is a class object
```

// Finally returning

```
return (new Pair<>(pairMatches, pedComputations)); // pedComputations and ped are Integer
```

Output reads : 
[Entity(name="frei", score=3, description="a word")=0]=1

Expected :
([(Entity(name="frei", score=3, description="a word"), 0)], 1)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return ("Entity(name=\"" + this.name + "\", score=" + this.score 
           + ", description=\"" + this.description + "\")");
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Hint; check your `toString()` method

Comment: @YCF_L I overrode toString for Entity class and its working fine, the standard output for pair is (value, value), do i need to override the toString() method ?

Comment: please share your method

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47518626/edit) your question and include your method

Comment: @YCF_L sorry about that, done

Comment: I suggest you try your own suggestion and override `toString()` in the `Pair` class.

Comment: I am using the standard Pair class from "javafx.util.Pair"; 
Not sure how to override it, already wasted hours on this, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within Pair class as you need to override `toString()` function in that class.

For example this code:

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair(1,2);
System.out.println(p);
```

will result in `1=2` being outputted.

You can either extend it the `Pair` class and just override `toString()` as your using `javafx.util.Pair` or create your own Pair class from scratch and override `toString()` there.

Example code on creating your own tuple can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)

Comment: @D M - Thank you, i finally did it the way you said, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @PeteRene I'm not DM unless I missed something, but make sure you accept the answer that helped you via the green tick on the left

Comment: @PeteRene learn [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)