# Is two dimentional array concept available in collection?

Tags: java

I want to know if I can create a 2D collection object just as a 2D array.
Kindly advice.

Comment: You can have a list of lists or collection of collections E.g. `List<List<String>>`. This way you can simulate a multi-dimensional collection.

Comment: @VPK, 2D array guarantees same size for all of it's elements. The list of lists does not and is same as jagged array.

Comment: Trivial, but if you just need a 2D array of objects, you can of course use `SomeObject[][]`.

Comment: Google's Table is another approach.  Just look for Guava, it has a collection of very nice, well collections and data structures.

Comment: @tsolakp, there's no doubt about `2D array guarantees same size for all of it's elements.`, but that can be the limitation of arrays and a good point for using the collection instead (depending upon specific req), isn't it?

Comment: @VPK. It depends. One can assume that arraylist of arraylists is two dimensional and just use first element`s size when iterating over all elements.

Comment: @tsolakp, yup that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you  can.
Example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question does not illustrate your intention clearly. But if you need a tuple, you should implement it or use external libraries.
For example this is an implementation of Pair (Tuple with two elements):

[A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)