# 2D static array of dynamic array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, matrix, arraylist

I have a 2D array as an input of NxM size, where N is known and static, and M actually grows dynamically and will be different for each index of the array[0...N-1].

I was thinking I could initialize my 2D array like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] array = new ArrayList[n];
```

but this leaves all sub-arrays initialized to null instead of an ArrayList instance. 
For example, calling

```
array[0].add(1);
```

crashes with a `NullPointerException`

How do I properly initialize the ArrayLists?

Comment: as an aside, consider using `List<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>(n);` rather than `ArrayList<Integer>[] array = new ArrayList[n];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialized the array itself, not the list at the 1st index (and so on...).

```
List<Integer>[] array = new ArrayList[n];
array[0] = new ArrayList<>();
array[0].add(1);
```

Anyway, I recommend you to avoid the array structure and pick `List<List<Integer>>` instead. Or create tuples class (more info at [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)).

Comment: My N is 100K-200K. Would looping through and initializing for each ArrayList be unavoidable?

Comment: The initialization is unavoidable regardless the number. Read the recommendation on the second part of my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you'll see at [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types.

You could use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>` or a `List<List<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> complex = new ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> simple = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
        simple.add((Integer)5555);
        complex.add(simple);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] array = new ArrayList[n];
```

Instead of doing it.
You can do like below:

```
List<List<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(2);
list1.add(list2);
ArrayList[] array = list1.toArray(new ArrayList[10]);
System.out.println(array[0]);
```