# for each nested for each

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, hashmap

I have a table that is the main table and then I have a two table(`a`,`b`) that have a foreign key of the main table. How can i retrieve by the `a table` and `b table` example:

```
table header is main id=1
```

then on the table `a` got inserted `one` , two than table `b` got inserted `one`, `two`

I want to display it by the row is `one-one` then `two-two` but right now i got an issue by displaying `one-one`, `one-two`, `two-one`, `two-two` my friend said that i must use hashmap the code below make me loop for unnecessary value

//this my code

```
ArrayList<Main>listMain = mainDAO.getlAllMain(Connection con);
for(Main listMain : listMain) {
  ArrayList<A> listA = aDAO.getallbyMainId(Connection con, int main);
  for(A listA : listA) {
    ArrayList<B> listB = bDAO.getallbyMainId(Connection con, int main);
    for(B listB : listB) {
      Main main = new Main();
      main.setMainName(listMain.getName());
      a.set(listA.getName);
      b.set(listB.getName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm lost. Can your friend help you?

Comment: `punctuation marks` srsly, use them... You really need to clarify your question, otherwise nobody can help you becaus nobody understands you. Also why do you need our help if your friend seems to have an idea?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc Thanks, that makes it a little bit better.

Comment: *"this my code"* well: no, this code does not compile.

Comment: Hey friend, you really need to read over this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    In your question, you post your title as "for each nested for each"... That is not a question. Also, you write what you have done, but you have not specifically asked any question at all. Revise the question and I would be 100% happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use nested for-each loops here.

Try an indexed for on the `listMain` and store the result of each iteration in a kind of tuple. This tuple could be stored in a `Map`. As your friend mentioned, you could use a `HashMap` for this. 
Something like this should do the trick:

```
    ArrayList<Main>listMain = mainDAO.getlAllMain(Connection con);
    Map<Integer, Pair<A, B>> map = new Hashmap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listMain.size(); i++) {
       ArrayList<A> listA = aDAO.getallbyMainId(Connection con, int main);
       ArrayList<B> listB = bDAO.getallbyMainId(Connection con, int main);
       A aValue = listA.get(i);
       B bValue = listB.get(i);
       map.put(i, new Pair(aValue, bValue));
    }
```

I'm using the apache-commons class [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) as a tuple here. See below to get more information about tuples in java. You could for example use a custom class for this purpose.

It is also possible to change the type of the pair content and the map key to be a `String` depending on the information u want to use later.

I hope i understood your problem correctly and that this answer is helping you.

**See also**

[A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)