# What is the best way to store two elements of different types

Tags: java

I have different elements of different types such as:

```
<0, "none">, <0, "constructor">, <0, "none">, <0, "method">, <1, "method">, <2, "constructor">, <2, "method">, <2, "constructor">
```

I would like to store them in a map or any other data structure without removing duplicates. I implemented the map as the following:

```
Map<Integer, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put(0, "none");
m1.put(0, "constructor");
m1.put(1, "none");
m1.put(0, "method");
```

The result of printing `m1` is `{0=method, 1=method, 2=constructor}` which I don't want. I want to show all the elements.

Comment: what about `Map<Integer,List<String>>`?

Comment: The point of a `Map` is to achieve lookup via the key.  That does not seem to be your purpose here. What is your purpose? Just to have a set to iterate over?

Comment: Have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples ?

Answer (score 5):

Create an object like below,

```
public class MyData {
private int id;
private String type;
// Constructor
// getters and setters
}
```

Then create MyData objects and store it in a list,

```
List<MyData> myData = new ArrayList<MyData>();

MyData data1 = new MyData(0, "none"); 
MyData data2 = new MyData(1, "method"); 
MyData data3 = new MyData(2, "constructor"); 
MyData data4 = new MyData(0, "none");

myData.add(data1); 
myData.add(data1); 
myData.add(data1); 
myData.add(data1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Guava has a multimap class that's perfect for this type of problem. Take a look at [multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 0):

The key in `Map` must be unique, so once you call `m1.put(0, "constructor");`, you replace the previous value mapped to 0, which was `"none"`. Either use multimap (`Map<Integer,List<String>>`), or use list/set of `Pair`s.