# Java: return types for a nested list

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I write the return type of a function if I want to return a nested `arraylist` in this function?

I actually want to return a tuple of two integers, but google says that we don't have such tuple things in Java, so that's why I think I should use the nested `ArrayList` to store the two `Integer` values I want.

I have googled online about the nested `ArrayList` in java. It says to declare a variable typed nested `ArrayList`, it should look like `ArrayList<ArrayList<type>>`, so I think maybe the `return` type should just be like `ArrayList<ArrayList<type>>`, but it doesn't work after I tried.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> some_function(object1, object2, ...)
```

Comment: There is a [`Pair`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class

Comment: You don't need a nested list to return two ints from a method. Just use `List<Integer>` or int array `int[]`. It would be helpful if you show your code.

Comment: @GBlodgett Which you would have to pull in JavaFX to use. I would not do that for just a `Pair` class.

Comment: Change int to Integer in ArrayList data type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)

Comment: You need the Object wrapper for the primitive `int`, so `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to achieve `return` `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> someFunction(int a,int b,int c,int d){

    ArrayList<Integer> intList =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList =new ArrayList<>();

    intList.add(a);
    intList.add(b);
    intList.add(c);
    intList.add(d);
    arrayList.add(intList);

    return arrayList;
}
```