# What is the best way to represent a composite key (key containing two values) of a Class and a Boolean

Tags: java

```
HashMap<Pair<Class<T>,Boolean>,String> abc = new HashMap<Pair<Class<T>,Boolean>,String>();
```

What is the best way to represent Pair here... Does Java offer anything?

My key will always be a {class,boolean} pair.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "represent"?  Do you just want to simplify the code?  Are you looking for something similar to a typedef in C++?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new wrapper class and use that as the key

```
class CustomKey
{
   String cls;
   boolean booleanValue;    
   // override equals and hashcode
}
```

Comment: is there a better way of doing this? Does java offer something similar to Entry?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `Pair` class in the Java library. There may be one in JDK7. Many large code bases end up with one.

However, are you sure a `Pair` is really what you want. A nicely encapsulated class with appropriate behaviour may be more appropriate. Both `Boolean` and `Pair` and notable for not having specific meaning.

If you really want efficiency, you might want to go for two `IdentityHashMap<Class<T>,String>`s.

FWIW, AFAIK, the closest to `Pair<Class<T>,Boolean>` in the Java library is `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicMarkableReference`, but you'll need to extend it to override `equals` and `hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

At this time Java does not have a Pair type or anything similar. I also did not find one in the Apache commons, although it is possible that I missed someting. In any case usually in this case a small immutable data class is created:

```
public class Key<T> {
  private final Class<T> cls;
  private final boolean flag;

  public Key(Class<T> cls, boolean flag) {
    this.cls = cls;
    this.flag = flag;   }

  public Class<T> getClass() {
    return cls;   }

  public boolean getFlag() {
    return flag;   }

  // equals and hashCode *must* be implemented -- see Effective Java for examples
}
```

Some people in this case will use public final methods instead -- it is a matter of taste plus how likely the class will get more complicated.

I have seen a couple of `Pair` or `Tuple` classes implemented if there is a need for the class outside of a single case (or if the developers have a functional background).

Answer (score 0):

There is no class called `Pair` in Java; but there is the `Map.Entry<K,V>` interface, and there are two public implementations of it: [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) and [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html).

If you find it ugly to use nested classes directly in your code, you could always create a Pair class:

```
public class Pair<Type1, Type2> extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Type1, Type2> {
    public Pair(Type1 t1, Type2 t2) {
        super(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

Or you could write your own like this:

```
public final class Pair<Type1, Type2> {
    public final Type1 first;
    public final Type2 second;

    public Pair(Type1 first, Type2 second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method to ease the pain of generics.
     */
    public static <T1, T2> Pair of(T1 first, T2 second) {
        return new Pair<T1, T2>(first, second);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        final Pair other = (Pair) obj; // no generics needed here
        if (this.first != other.first &&
            (this.first == null || !this.first.equals(other.first)))
            return false;
        if (this.second != other.second &&
            (this.second == null || !this.second.equals(other.second)))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 37 * hash + (this.first != null ? this.first.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 37 * hash + (this.second != null ? this.second.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches here... create a key{class, Boolean} -> {string} or i could also do this.

{class} -> {Boolean, string}

the first approach has 1 level of indirection which the second approach has 2... what are the pros and cons here? Is the second approach bad?

Comment: Posted as its own question: composite key v/s 2 levels of indirection [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967378/composite-key-v-s-2-levels-of-indirection]