# How to return the index Element in an Elements list using jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have two lists I need to both iterate at the same time, getting the same n-th element from them. This how I solved:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
[...]
int idx = 0;

for(Element A : ListA) {    
    String B = ListB.eq(idx).text();
    System.out.println(A.text()+ " " + B);
    ++idx;
}
```

In order to return the following output:

A1 B1

A2 B2

...

An Bn

It'd be cleaner if I could extract from `ListA` the current n-th element index. But how? I did not find any suitable method.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365810?

Comment: Neater. Thank you. But I still wonder why it isnt's possible to get the index of the item I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it works, but you can try `ListA.indexOf(A)` to get the current index.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `Elements` class' hierarchy - [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html). It extends `ArrayList` and if you scroll down you'll see that it inherits `get`, so the following code snippet is possible:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("some css selector");
Element e = elements.get(index);
System.out.println(e.get(anotherIndex).html());
```

So you can use an index to get an specific `Element` from `Elements` list.