# Overriding "equals" method: how to figure out the type of the parameter?

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I'm trying to override `equals` method for a parameterized class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Tuple))
        return false;

    Tuple<E> other = (Tuple<E>) obj; //unchecked cast
    if (!a0.equals(other.a0) && !a0.equals(other.a1)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!a1.equals(other.a1) && !a1.equals(other.a0)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I make sure that `<E>` of the `other` object is the same as `this`?

Comment: BTW doesn't this logic imply that "a","a" and "a","b" are equal?

Wouldn't it be easier to just write "if a0=a0 and a1=a1, or a0=a1 and a1=a0..."

Comment: If you allow your a0 and a1 to be null, make sure you add checks for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it by retaining a reference to `Class<E>` type.  However, in my opinion, *equality tests should be about the values the objects represent rather than the concrete types the values get expressed*.

A classic example of this is the Collections API for example.  `new ArrayList<String>().equals(new LinkedList<Object>())` returns `true`.  While these have completely different types, they represent the same value, namely "an empty collection".

Personally, should two `Tuple`s that represent the same data (e.g. `("a", "b")`) be not equal, because one is of type `Tuple<String>` while the other is `Tuple<Object>`?

Comment: How about Id<User> and Id<Article>, even if the actual value inside the object (the database id) is the same, I don't think they should be considered equal since they represent IDs for different DB columns.

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation, but I would also include in here what to write in the equals method when the parameter type is not important in order to remove the compiler warnings.

For others reading this, There is another answer on this page that mentions the <?> wildcard and it's use here.

Answer (score 5):

Because of erasure you can't.  About the best you could do is store in the tuple class the type you plan for the Tuple to hold in a "java.lang.Class" field member.  Then you could compare those fields to make sure the tuple class is holding the same types.

Also see this thread:
[What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

It would help if you post more about your class.  I'm thinking the unchecked cast and your number of fields you equate means it should be Tuple<E,F> no?

EDIT:  here is a useful Pair class I use regularly (you can adapt your Tuple class if needed).  Note, similiar to suggestions by others this class just lets the contained members decide the question of equality.  Your use case is what should determine whether equality is really based on the type of the contained members.

```
/**
 * Adapted from http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5132045
 * 
 * 
 * @author Tim Harsch
 *
 * @param <L>
 * @param <R>
 */
public class Pair<L, R> {

    private final L left;
    private final R right;

    public R getRight() {
        return right;
    } // end getter

    public L getLeft() {
        return left;
    } // end getter

    public Pair(final L left, final R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    } // end constructor

    public static <A, B> Pair<A, B> create(A left, B right) {
        return new Pair<A, B>(left, right);
    } // end factory method

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Pair<?,?>))
            return false;

        final Pair<?, ?> other = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
        return equal(getLeft(), other.getLeft()) && equal(getRight(), other.getRight());
    } // end method

    public static final boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            return o2 == null;
        }
        return o1.equals(o2);
    } // end method

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hLeft = getLeft() == null ? 0 : getLeft().hashCode();
        int hRight = getRight() == null ? 0 : getRight().hashCode();

        return hLeft + (37 * hRight);
    } // end method

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('<');
        if( left == null ) {
            sb.append("null");
        } else {
            sb.append(left.toString());
        } // end if
        sb.append(',');
        if( right == null ) {
            sb.append("null");
        } else {
            sb.append(right.toString());
        } // end if
        sb.append('>');
        return sb.toString();
    } // end method
} // end class
```

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem myself, and in my -particular- case, I didn't need to know the type E.

For example:

```
public class Example<E> {
    E value;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Example<?> other = (Example<?>) obj;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the above code, there is no unchecked cast because of using `Example<?>`.  The type parameter wildcard '?' saves the day.

Comment: Never thought to use <?> like that. This is a fantastic answer, since most of the time, during an equals check in a Parameterized class, one really shouldn't care what types the generics are. +1

Comment: 1. the question was how to check that the type parameters are equal, and this answer only avoids an "unsafe cast" warning while the type parameters aren't checked --> downvoted  2. there really are cases where you want instances for different types to be regarded as unequal

Answer (score 3):

Since [generics are erased at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you basically can't. At runtime, any type parameter is gone, and as far as the JVM is concerned, they are exactly the same in all respects.

The way to work around that is to store a `Class` field that represents the type, and create the object with that type in the constructor.

A sample constructor:

```
public class Tuple < E > {

    public Tuple(Class<E> c) {
        //store the class
    }

}
```

Or you could use a factory:

```
public static <E> Tuple <E> getTuple(Class<E> type) {
    // Create and return the tuple, 
    // just store that type variable in it 
    // for future use in equals.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, you can't do this at compile time; the information is gone. Such are the consequences of [**type erasure**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). An alternative is to store the parameter as a `Class` instance, and then look it up later.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions to retain a reference to `E`'s type with a `Class` object seem *inefficient* (that's a lot of pointless references to a `Class` taking up memory) and pointless for your problem.

It's not generally true that `Foo<Bar>` and`Foo<Baz>` should be unequal. So you don't need `E`. And, in the code you wrote, you don't even need it to compile. Simply cast to `Tuple<?>`, since that is truly all you know about `Tuple` at that point. It still compiles and all.

If you are passed `Tuple`s with data of two wildly different types, those elements will not be `equals`, and your method will return `false`, as desired. (One hopes -- depends on those types implementing `equals` sanely.)

Comment: I don't see how retaining a reference to E's type take up memory; each `Class` object has to be retained by the classloader/JVM anyway, so the only extra memory you'd use is about an extra four bytes for a pointer (8 for 64-bit systems).

Comment: That's right, it's the references that take up the space. 4/8 bytes per object may or may not be trivial depending on how many instances are out there. As it doesn't help solve the problem at hand it seems, I'd call those references wasteful at any size.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html

Comment: Good thing too, because I would have downvoted you.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=lmgtfy

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic - do you realise that according to your implementation, Tuple(a0, a1) is equal to Tuple(a1, a1)?  I suspect that's not what you want...

On-topic, as others have said, erasure makes this impossible.  But you should reconsider why you want this - equality checking only happens at runtime, and **generics are only compile-time**.  Conceptually, a *variable* has generic parameters, but an *object* does not.  Thus when you're comparing the equality of objects, the generic parameters do not matter at all; you can't take any appropriate action based on them at runtime anyway.

Object equality, and generic parameter co-/contra-variance, are two orthogonal concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, why does the class E need to be equal?  and how do you want to treat subclasses of E?

Anyway, given that here is a code sample that may help you:

```
public class Example<T> {

  T t;

  public Example(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "string";
    final Integer i = 1;
    final Number n = 1;

    final Example<String> exampleString = new Example<String>(s);
    final Example<Integer> exampleInteger = new Example<Integer>(i);
    final Example<Number> exampleNumber = new Example<Number>(n);

    System.out.println("exampleString subclass "  + exampleString.t.getClass());
    System.out.println("exmapleIntger subclass " + exampleInteger.t.getClass());
    System.out.println("exmapleNumber subclass " + exampleNumber.t.getClass());
    System.out.println("Integer equals Number = " + 
        exampleInteger.t.equals(exampleNumber.t));
  }
}
```

You can call t.getClass() to get class information about the type of T (assuming it is not null, of course.)

I hope this helps.