# Need flexible Java key/value collection class for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, collections, jcombobox

I have a model class that stores keys and values:

```
public class KeyValue {

    private Object key;
    private String value;

    KeyValue () {
    }

    KeyValue (Object key, String value) {
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public Object getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
    public void setKey(Object key) {
        this.key=key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

I use this class to populate a `JComboBox`'s Model:

```
for (int i = 0; i < universes.length; i++) {
    ComboBox_Universes.addItem(new KeyValue(infoObject.ID,infoObject.title));
}
```

I would like to refactor this logic to use a Java collection class (call it `KeyValueCollection`) that can support two objectives:

1) the `KeyValueCollection` can be used to populate the `JComboBox`'s Model.  Something like:

```
//get a KeyValueCollection filled with data from helper class
KeyValueCollection universeCollection = Repository.getUniverseCollection();

//use this collection as the JComboBox's model
ComboBox_Universes.setModel(universeCollection);
```

2) I can use the `KeyValueCollection` to convert a key to a value:

```
//ID retrieve from another control
int universeID = (int)this.Table_Values.getModel().getValueAt(row, COLUMN_ID);

//convert ID to name
String universeName = universeCollection.get(universeID).getValue();
```

In the .NET world, I would use the KeyedCollection class for this, but I'm not very familiar with Java.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom class like this one (run main function to see its behavior) :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyValueComboboxModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel, Map<String, String> {

    private TreeMap<String,String> values = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    private Map.Entry<String, String> selectedItem = null;

    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        this.selectedItem = (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>) anItem;
        fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1);
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(values.entrySet());
        return list.get(index);
    }



    public int getSize() {
        return values.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        values.clear();
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return values.containsKey(key);
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return values.containsValue(value);
    }

    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        return values.entrySet();
    }

    public String get(Object key) {
        return values.get(key);
    }

    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return values.keySet();
    }

    public String put(String key, String value) {
        return values.put(key, value);
    }

    public String remove(Object key) {
        return values.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return values.size();
    }

    public Collection<String> values() {
        return values.values();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return values.isEmpty();
    }

    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m) {
        values.putAll(m);
    }


    private static String entryToString(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
        String str = "" + entry.getKey() + "->" + entry.getValue();
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>(){{
            put("1","blue");
            put("2","red");
            put("3","white");
            put("4","black");
        }};

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()));

        KeyValueComboboxModel model = new KeyValueComboboxModel();
        model.putAll(map);

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(model);
        combo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer(){

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                if(value instanceof Map.Entry){
                    Map.Entry<String,String> entry = (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>) value;
                    String str = entryToString(entry);
                    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, str, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                }
                return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            }

        });

        final JLabel lab = new JLabel("Nothing selected");

        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(combo.getSelectedItem()!=null){
                    lab.setText(entryToString((java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>) combo.getSelectedItem()));
                } else {
                    lab.setText("");
                }

            }

        });

        f.getContentPane().add(combo,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(lab,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setSize(300,80);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

EDIT : to handle the selected item and keys, you may add these methods:

```
public void setSelectedKey(String key){
    selectedItem = values.ceilingEntry(key);
    setSelectedItem(key);
}

public void setSelectedItem(String key, String value){
    values.put(key, value);
    setSelectedKey(key);
}
```

By default, values are ordered following the natural order of the keys (alphabetical order of the keys, here, because these are `String`). If you need an other ordering, add a `java.util.Comparator` to the `TreeMap` (see TreeMap documentation).

Comment: Three questions:
1.  What is the syntax for setting the SelectedItem?  The Foo part of this is [foo]ling me...Sorry.
Map.Entry<String,String> item = new Foo<String,String>("2","red");
model.setSelectedItem(item);

2.  If I wanted a setSelectedKey() method, then I would need to find the correct Map.Entry from the TreeMap, then call setSelectedItem, correct?

3.  Ideally, the combobox's values would be sorted alphabetically.  I'm assuming that I need to sort the HashMap's values.  Is there another, simpler way?

Comment: Shouldn't the setSelectedKey() method read:

public void setSelectedKey(String key) {
    //call the method that sets the variable and fires the event
    setSelectedItem( values.ceilingEntry(key) );
}

Comment: `Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>(){{
            put("1","blue");
            put("2","red");
            put("3","white");
            put("4","black");
        }};` is a really bad way to add entries to a map, since it creates an anonymous class just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The Map (implementation HashMap) is a Key-Value class.

It converts from key to value using the method #get.

There are also method to access all keys, all values and so on. So you should have no problem to fill a model with it.

It also contains a Key-Value pair that is called Map.Entry.

Answer (score 1):

What about [`java.util.Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations?

with [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), for example, you can have:

```
Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<Object, String>();
map.put(key, value);
Object value = map.get(key);
```

However, you can't directly populate the `JComboBox` with the `Map`. You can add all keys to the `JComboBox`, and then get the corresponding values when needed. Adding can be done in many ways, two of which:

- `new JComboBox(map.keySet().toArray(new Object[]));`
- by a loop:

  ```
  for (Object key : map.keySet() {
      comboBox.addItem(key);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your second requirement suggests that you want a [Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), but [ComboboxModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) is a [ListModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html), which suggests that you'll want to be able to efficiently retrieve elements by "index".

I don't believe any of the standard collections can do this for you as simply as you'd like. You can either create a Map, and then copy the values to a separate List/ComboboxModel, or you could use something like [IndexedList](http://www.purpletech.com/code/doc/com/purpletech/util/IndexedList.html) (a List implementation that maintains an index Map).

Answer (score 0):

I think that a plain `HashMap<Object,String>` can address most of your needs:

```
// Build the map
Map<Object,String> map = new HashMap<Object,String>();
for(InfoObject io : universes) 
   map.put(io.ID,io.title);


// Populate the ComboBox
for(String s : map.values())
   ComboBox_Universes.addItem(s);


// Convert ID to name
int universeID = (int)this.Table_Values.getModel().getValueAt(row, COLUMN_ID);
String universeName = map.get(universeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
/**
 * This class is slightly modified version of the Pair class from this thread:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java
 * As suggested in the thread above, I have made first & second to be final members.
 * I have made it into an Map.Entry<K,V> type, so it is suitable to be an element
 * of any Java Hash map...
 *
 * @author Dejan Lekic - http://dejan.lekic.org
 */
public class Pair<KeyT, ValueT> implements Map.Entry<KeyT, ValueT> {

    protected KeyT first;
    protected ValueT second;

    public Pair(final KeyT argFirst, final ValueT argSecond) {
        super();
        this.first = argFirst;
        this.second = argSecond;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashFirst = (first != null) ? first.hashCode() : 0;
        int hashSecond = (second != null) ? second.hashCode() : 0;

        return (hashFirst + hashSecond) * hashSecond + hashFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Pair) {
            Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
            return ((this.first == otherPair.first
                    || (this.first != null && otherPair.first != null
                    && this.first.equals(otherPair.first)))
                    && (this.second == otherPair.second
                    || (this.second != null && otherPair.second != null
                    && this.second.equals(otherPair.second))));
        } // if
        return false;
    } // equals() method

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // previously we used " - " as a separator. Now we will use the 0x1f character, called the UNIT
        // SEPARATOR to separate two fields in a String object. See the Sise class for more information.
        return first + "\u001f" + second;
    }

    public KeyT getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(final KeyT argFirst) {
        this.first = argFirst;
    }

    public ValueT getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(final ValueT argSecond) {
        this.second = argSecond;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueT setValue(final ValueT argNewValue) {
        ValueT oldValue = second;
        second = argNewValue;
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueT getValue() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyT getKey() {
        return first;
    }
} // Pair class

// $Id: Pair.java 149 2012-01-13 12:30:59Z dejan $
```