# Ensure that objects implement Comparable

Tags: java, generics, compare

I have a litte problem and was wondering how to solve it. I have a generic class `Tuple<A,B>` and now I would like to sort their tuples according to A and B. It should look like this:

Unsorted:

```
(1,5)
(2,8)
(6,8)
(1,4)
(2,4)
```

Sorted:

```
(1,4)
(1,5)
(2,4)
(2,8)
(6,8)
```

For that reason I thought of implementing a generic compare method (`public int compareTo(Tuple<A, B> other)`) in the Tuple class. The only problem is that all objects that you could parameterize the class for (e.g. A=Integer, B=String) have to implement the compareTo method too in order for this whole thing to work.

Is there a way to ensure that all objects the Tuple can hold implement the Comparable interface?

Or are there any other suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use recursive type bounds (see also Item 27 of [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)) to specify that the components of the tuple extend Comparable, like so:

```
 public class Tuple<A extends Comparable<? super A>, B extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Comparable<Tuple<A, B>> {
    A valueA;
    B valueB;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple<A, B> tuple) {
        // Implement comparison logic
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This allows you to specify different types for the components of the tuple (Tuple<Integer, String>).

Comment: I prefer `A extends Comparable<? super A>`, but +1 for implementing Comparable on the Tuple itself. I should have remembered that.

Comment: You shouldn't use `A extends Comparable<A>`... this won't work with older classes that implement raw `Comparable`, among other things. mmyers's signature with `A extends Comparable<? super A>` is correct.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've edited my answer so as not to mislead, and have upvoted mmyers' version.

Comment: Hmm.  When I try implementing the comparator, I get the error:  'The operator '<' is undefined for argument types A, A  ...

Answer (score 7):

If you declare the class as

```
public class Tuple<A extends Comparable<? super A>,
                   B extends Comparable<? super B>> { ...
```

then that ensures that both A and B are self-comparable. You can then call `compareTo()` on any object of type A or B that you have in the class.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Any class you specify will have to extend Comparable.

```
public class Tuple<? extends Comparable> {
}
```

Comment: I realize you wrote this without seeing the original generic declaration of Tuple, so I can't blame you for missing the A and B parameters. But even so, it will cause a warning because you haven't parameterized Comparable.