# Java: How to write a `zip` function? What should be the return type?

Tags: java

What should be the return type of a `zip` function? (`zip` as in most other languages, e.g. [read here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip))

I thought about some Pair-type but that does not exist in Java. It is often states that this is because a specialized Pair-class is better than a general one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) question). However, this is not possible in a general `zip` function.

Comment: There is a Pair class. You just wrote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

Comment: Why wouldn't a MAP work ?  It will store key, value pairs and I've done Object based keys.

Comment: @jim: Do you mean `Collections.singletonMap`? Yes, that works, but it's immutable. :-)

Comment: How about `Map.Entry` then? That's only... half-immutable ;) Seriously though, just write a Pair class.

Comment: May want to take a look at this thread on the OpenJDK core-libs-dev mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-March/003973.html

Comment: @Brabster: I often enough had question gettings close when doing this. Also, most questions here were answered while I already had that relation to `zip`. As people have mostly ignored it and most answers were unrelated to `zip`, I reformulated my question. (It is still mostly the same question.)

Comment: In short, you should make a meaningful class which wraps the two values you want to hold.

Comment: Instead of using an array or tuple where each value has no particular meaning. You should have a data value class where the fields are given meaningful names. i.e. use object orientated programing.  Without knowing what your intended use I can't be more specific.

Comment: @Peter: I intend to implement a `zip` function. See my question.

Comment: See the answers section for some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you appear to be determined to ignore people with many years Java experience, here is code which does the same as the zip function in python.

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> zip(List<T>... lists) {
    List<List<T>> zipped = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    for (List<T> list : lists) {
        for (int i = 0, listSize = list.size(); i < listSize; i++) {
            List<T> list2;
            if (i >= zipped.size())
                zipped.add(list2 = new ArrayList<T>());
            else
                list2 = zipped.get(i);
            list2.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return zipped;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
        List<List<Integer>> zipped = zip(x, y);
        System.out.println(zipped);
}
```

Prints

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: To translate your post into an answer to my question: I can just use `List<T>` instead of `Pair<T,T>`. Still doesn't work though if I want to `zip` lists of different types.

Comment: All types extend Object and you can use this for all types.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't explicitly a pair (or any tuple) in the standard JRE.

There was a [discussion on the subject](http://groups.google.com/group/javaposse/browse_thread/thread/9ed080d9eb09ee60) on the javaposse Google group that you might be interested in, that links off to a post by [Dick Wall on why Java needs a Pair and a Triple](http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3813031_1/Java-Needs-to-Get-a-Pair-and-a-Triple.htm), plus a [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java).

---

Update - original question was whether there was a Pair in Java. This answer may no longer make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering the Java 'zip' qusetion purely out of interest and I do ***not*** advise this solution - which is not a function, although you could have it build a list of lists if you like.

It is possible to iterate over two lists in the same for loop using the following.

```
Iterator<Object> iterA=listA.iterator();
Iterator<Object> iterB=listB.iterator();
for (Object a=iterA.next(), b=iterB.next(); 
     iterA.hasNext()&&iterB.hasNext(); 
     a=iterA.next(), b=iterB.next()) {
   ...
}
```

It is ***not*** a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start.

```
public class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    private T1 first;
    private T2 second;

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T1 getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public T2 getSecond()
    {
        return second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have made pair class tuned almost to perfection :P

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> implements Iterable<Object>, Cloneable{

    public static <X, Y> Pair<X, Y> makePair(X x, Y y){
        return new Pair<X, Y>(x, y);
    }

    public static <X> Pair<X, X[]> makePairFromArray(X... xs){
        if (xs.length == 0)
            return new Pair<X, X[]>(null, null);
        if (xs.length == 1)
            return new Pair<X, X[]>(xs[0], null);
        return new Pair<X, X[]>(xs[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(xs, 1, xs.length-1));
    }

    public static <X, Y> Pair<X, Y> reverse(Pair<Y, X> original){
        return makePair(original.getSecond(), original.getFirst());
    }

    public static synchronized <X> void swap(Pair<X, X> swapped){
        X tmp = swapped.getFirst();
        swapped.setFirst(swapped.getSecond());
        swapped.setSecond(tmp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <X, Y> List<Object> asObjectList(Pair<X, Y> pair){
        return asList((Pair<Object, Object>) pair);
    }

    public static <X, Y> Object[] asObjectArray(Pair<X, Y> pair, Object[] array){
        return asObjectList(pair).toArray(array);
    }

    public static <X> List<X> asList(Pair<X, X> pair){
        ArrayList<X> list = new ArrayList<X>();
        list.add(pair.getFirst());
        list.add(pair.getSecond());
        return list;
    }

    public static <X> X[] asArray(Pair<X, X> pair, X[] array){
        return asList(pair).toArray(array);
    }

    public static <X> Iterator<X> typedIterator(Pair<X, X> pair){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Iterator<X> it = (Iterator<X>) pair.iterator();
        return it;
    }

    public static <X> boolean isSymmetric(Pair<X, X> pair){
        return pair.equals(reverse(pair));
    }

    public static <X> boolean isReflexive(Pair<X, X> pair){
        X x1 = pair.getFirst();
        X x2 = pair.getSecond();

        if (x1 == null && x2 == null) return true;
        if (x1 == null && x2 != null) return false;
        if (x1 != null && x2 == null) return false;
        return x1.equals(x2);
    }

    public static <X, Y, Z> boolean isTransitive(Pair<X, Y> first, Pair<Y, Z> second){
        Y y1 = first.getSecond();
        Y y2 = second.getFirst();

        if (y1 == null && y2 == null) return true;
        if (y1 == null && y2 != null) return false;
        if (y1 != null && y2 == null) return false;
        return y1.equals(y2);
    }

    public static synchronized <X, Y> Pair<X, Y> immutablePair(Pair<X, Y> pair){
        final Pair<X, Y> wrapped = pair;
        return new Pair<X, Y>(null, null){

            @Override
            public X getFirst() {
                return wrapped.getFirst();
            }

            @Override
            public Y getSecond() {
                return wrapped.getSecond();
            }

            @Override
            public void setFirst(X first) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public void setSecond(Y second) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return wrapped.hashCode();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return wrapped.equals(obj);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return wrapped.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
                return wrapped.iterator();
            }

            @Override
            public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                return wrapped.clone();
            }

            @Override
            public Pair<X, Y> copy() {
                return wrapped.copy();
            }

        };
    }

    public static synchronized <X, Y> Pair<X, Y> synchronizedPair(Pair<X, Y> pair){
        final Pair<X, Y> wrapped = pair;
        return new Pair<X, Y>(null, null){

            @Override
            public synchronized X getFirst() {
                return wrapped.getFirst();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void setFirst(X first) {
                wrapped.setFirst(first);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized Y getSecond() {
                return wrapped.getSecond();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void setSecond(Y second) {
                wrapped.setSecond(second);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized int hashCode() {
                return wrapped.hashCode();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return wrapped.equals(obj);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized String toString() {
                return wrapped.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized Iterator<Object> iterator() {
                return wrapped.iterator();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                return wrapped.clone();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized Pair<X, Y> copy() {
                return wrapped.copy();
            }

        };
    }

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 second) {
        super();
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public Pair(){
        super();
        this.first = null;
        this.second = null;
    }

    public Pair(Pair<T1, T2> copy) {
        first = copy.first;
        second = copy.second;
    }

    private T1 first;
    private T2 second;

    public T1 getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(T1 first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public T2 getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(T2 second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((second == null) ? 0 : second.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Pair other = (Pair) obj;
        if (first == null) {
            if (other.first != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
            return false;
        if (second == null) {
            if (other.second != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!second.equals(other.second))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Object>(){
            private int it = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return it != 2;
            }

            @Override
            public Object next() {
                return (it++) == 0 ? first : second;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public Pair<T1, T2> copy(){
        return makePair(first, second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but with modern Java you could use the [`Streams.zip(Stream, Stream, BiFunction)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method from the Guava library, which provides the same functionality as Python's `zip` function.