# Scala for loop over two lists simultaneously

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `List[Message]` and a `List[Author]` which have the same number of items, and should be ordered so that at each index, the `Message` is from the `Author`.

I also have class that we'll call here `SmartMessage`, with a constructor taking 2 arguments: a `Message` and the corresponding `Author`.

What I want to do, is to create a `List[SmartMessage]`, combining the data of the 2 simple lists.

Extra question: does `List` preserve insertion order in Scala? Just to make sure I create `List[Message]` and a `List[Author]` with same ordering.

Comment: `zip` will only suffice up to 3 lists. If you have more, you might like to look at this question / answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17072064/770361

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
val ms: List[Message] = ???
val as: List[Author] = ???

var sms = for ( (m, a) <- (ms zip as)) yield new SmartMessage(m, a)
```

If you don't like `for-comprehensions` you could use `map`:

```
var sms = (ms zip as).map{ case (m, a) => new SmartMessage(m, a)}
```

Method `zip` creates collection of pairs. In this case `List[(Message, Author)]`.

You could also use `zipped` method on `Tuple2` (and on `Tuple3`):

```
var sms = (ms, as).zipped.map{ (m, a) => new SmartMessage(m, a)}
```

As you can see you don't need pattern matching in `map` in this case.

**Extra**

`List` is `Seq` and `Seq` preserves order. See [scala collections overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html).

There are 3 main branches of collections: [Seq](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/seqs.html), [Set](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html) and [Map](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html).

- [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) preserves order of elements.
- [Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set) contains no duplicate elements.
- [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map) contains mappings from keys to values.

`List` in scala is [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), so you should prepend elements to it, not append. See [Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) of scala collections.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when zipping a list with data together with an empty list is that the result will also be an empty list. So you might want to make sure your code is okay with that. Otherwise you could check for one of the lists being empty first or use zipAll() with default values.