# How can I loop through two String arrays in in one loop

Tags: java, loops

So I want the result to be "Today Blue" and "Tomorrow Red" how can I do that by looping?

```
String[] sections = 
        {
          "Blue",
          "Red"
        };

       String[] stringDay = 
        {
          "Today",
          "Tomorrow"
        };

    for(String sectionsLoop : sections)
    {
        System.out.println(stringDay + " " + sectionsLoop);
    }
```

Comment: Use an old loop.

Comment: You an index in the loop: `for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(sections.length, stringNumber.length); i++)`

Comment: HI there sorry, I explained wrong, I edited my question

Comment: I want two string to be put together

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sections.length && i < stringDay.length; i++) { System.out.println(stringDay[i] + " " + sections[i]); }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over two arrays simultaneously using for each loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318707/iterating-over-two-arrays-simultaneously-using-for-each-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

  String[] selection =  new String[] {"Blue","red"};
  String[] day = new String[] {"today","tomorrow"};

  for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; ++i) {
      System.out.println(day[i] + " " + selection[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great this worked thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the traditional for loop but you have to make sure both arrays from the same size or do the below to prevent arrayOutOfIndex

```
    int size = sections.length > stringNumber.length ?sections.length : stringNumber.length;
    for (int i = 0; i <size ; i++) {
        if (sections.length < i) {
            System.out.println(sections[i]);
        }
        if (stringNumber.length < i) {
            System.out.println(stringNumber[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to update your answer..