# Merge two string arrays to list of element pairs

Tags: java, arrays, guava

I have two arrays with different size:

```
added_items[1, 2, 3]
deleted_items[3, 4]
```

My goal is to convert these arrays to list of the following pairs:

```
list {
    added: 1, deleted 3
    added: 2, deleted 4
    added: 3, deleted: null
}
```

Would be good if your share the simplest way how I can achieve this using guava, apache libraries, etc to avoid too many custom logic with for each etc..

I would really appreciate any answers.

Comment: What is a `pair`?  Will it be your own class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833814/java-how-to-write-a-zip-function-what-should-be-the-return-type

Comment: Yeah, pair it would be own class.

Comment: I seriously doubt there's anything more effective than just the direct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int max = added_items.length > deleted_items.length ? added_items.length : deleted_items.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        Integer added = (i < added_items.length) ? added_items[i] : null;
        Integer deleted = (i < deleted_items.length) ? deleted_items[i] : null;
        pairs.add(new Pair(added, deleted));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String[] MERGE = ArrayUtils.addAll(added_items, deleted_items);
```

Or Try:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

concat(asList(added_items), asList(deleted_items))
```