# Creating a list of pairs in java

Tags: java, list

Which class would work best for a non-ordered list of pairs? I'll be taking a bunch of (float,short) pairs and will need to be able to perform simple math (like multiplying the pair together to return a single float, etc). List only takes one argument, and HashMap won't allow duplicates (as far as I know). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the `Entry<U,V>` class that `HashMap` uses but you'll be stuck with its semantics of `getKey` and `getValue`:

```
List<Entry<Float,Short>> pairList = //...
```

My preference would be to create your own simple `Pair` class:

```
public class Pair<L,R> {
    private L l;
    private R r;
    public Pair(L l, R r){
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }
    public L getL(){ return l; }
    public R getR(){ return r; }
    public void setL(L l){ this.l = l; }
    public void setR(R r){ this.r = r; }
}
```

Then of course make a `List` using this new class, e.g.:

```
List<Pair<Float,Short>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<Float,Short>>();
```

You can also always make a `List`s of `List`s, but it becomes difficult to enforce sizing (that you have only pairs) and you would be required, as with arrays, to have consistent typing.

Comment: But I would definitely just make the placeholder class and then add instances of it to a list-- call a spade a spade...

Comment: Let's say I was going to do this without a new class. I'm thinking of just running two lists of the appropriate type. Why does it complain when I do: private List<Float> floatList = new List<Float>(); but not when I leave the assignment operator out and just have private List<Float> floatList; ? It still needs to be instantiated doesn't it?

Comment: @V1rtua1An0ma1y: because `List` is an interface, you need an implementation, like, say, `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: You have a small typo error in the code, in getL() and getR(), it should be "return l;" and "return r;" instead of "return L;" and "return R;".

Comment: You might also want to make `Pair` immutable.

Comment: Sorry, I might sound silly, do we really need a constructor here - what purpose does it solve?

Answer (score 11):

Use a List of custom class instances.  The custom class is some sort of Pair or Coordinate or whatever.  Then just

```
List<Coordinate> = new YourFavoriteListImplHere<Coordinate>()
```

This approach has the advantage that it makes satisfying this requirement "perform simple math (like multiplying the pair together to return a single float, etc)" clean, because your custom class can have methods for whatever maths you need to do...

Answer (score 4):

just fixing some small mistakes in Mark Elliot's code:

```
public class Pair<L,R> {
    private L l;
    private R r;
    public Pair(L l, R r){
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }
    public L getL(){ return l; }
    public R getR(){ return r; }
    public void setL(L l){ this.l = l; }
    public void setR(R r){ this.r = r; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Mark E has proposed, but no need to recreate the wheel, if you don't mind relying on 3rd party libs.

Apache Commons has tuples already defined:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<L,R>
```

Apache Commons is so pervasive, I typically already have it in my projects, anyway.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Comment: That wouldn't have worked 9 years ago but would work now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create your own pair class (see [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)).  Then make a List of that pair class you created

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) has support for primitive pairs and primitive collections. This can reduce the amount of boxing required instead of using `Float` and `Short` wrapper objects, if that is a concern.

```
@Test
public void floatShortPairs() 
{
    MutableList<FloatShortPair> pairs = Lists.mutable.of(
            PrimitiveTuples.pair(10.0f, (short) 10),
            PrimitiveTuples.pair(5.0f, (short) 5),
            PrimitiveTuples.pair(10.0f, (short) 5),
            PrimitiveTuples.pair(5.0f, (short) 10));

    FloatList floatList = pairs.collectFloat(pair -> pair.getOne() * pair.getTwo());
    DoubleList doubleList = pairs.collectDouble(pair -> pair.getOne() * pair.getTwo());

    FloatList expectedFloats = FloatLists.mutable.of(100.0f, 25.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedFloats, floatList);

    DoubleList expectedDoubles = DoubleLists.mutable.of(100.0, 25.0, 50.0, 50.0);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedDoubles, doubleList);
}
```

The `PrimitiveTuples` factory can create all combinations of primitive to primitive pairs. The `MutableList` interface has eager operations available directly on the collection to convert to other Object collections or primitive collections. These methods are prefixed with `collect`. `MutableList` extends the `java.util.List` interface.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

For a non-ordered list of pairs where you need to perform simple math operations on the pairs, a suitable class to use would be an ArrayList of a custom Pair class.
you can try this code :

```
public class Pair {
    private float floatValue;
    private short shortValue;

    public Pair(float floatValue, short shortValue) {
        this.floatValue = floatValue;
        this.shortValue = shortValue;
    }

    public float getFloatValue() {
        return floatValue;
    }

    public short getShortValue() {
        return shortValue;
    }

    public float multiply() {
        return floatValue * shortValue;
    }
}
```

In this code, we have a Pair class that holds a float value and a short value. It has a constructor to initialize the pair, getter methods to access the values, and a multiply method to perform the multiplication operation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Mark E has proposed, you have to come up with your own. Just to help you a bit, there is a neat article http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/building-your-own-literals-in-java-tuples-and-maps/ which gives you a really neat way of creating tuples and maps that might be something you might want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiplicities, you can put it in map that maps pair to ammount.
This way there will only be one pair of given values, but it can represent multiple occurances.

Then if you have lot of repeatet values and want to perform some operation on all values, you can save lot of computations.

Answer (score 0):

although HashMap does not allowed duplicated keys it can be used in this way:
`Map<String, List<String>> mapWithDuplicates = new Map<String, List<String>>();`

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a list of pairs using an `ArrayList` that contains *n* `Map.Entry` objects for a list of size *n* seems to me wasteful in both time and space.

So I created my own `PairList<L, R>` class that implements `List<Map.Entry<L, R>>` and stores the *n* entries in a backing list of size *2 * n*:

```
interface PairList<L, R> extends List<Map.Entry<L, R>> {
  static <L, R> PairList<L, R> of(); // creates empty mutable list
  boolean add(int index, L l, R r); // adds a pair
  boolean addAll(PairList<L, R> list); // adds all pairs in another list
  Map.Entry<L, R> set(int i, L l, R r); // updates pair i
  void forEach(BiConsumer<L, R> consumer); // iterates over pairs
  L left(int i); // returns the left part of pair i
  R right(int i); // returns the right part of pair i
  List<L> leftList(); // returns the left slice
  List<R> rightList(); // returns the right slice
  List<T> transform(BiFunction<L, R, T> f); // applies a mapping function
  ImmutablePairList<L, R> immutable(); // returns an immutable copy
}
```

The list contains the key of the first pair, the value of the first pair, the key of the second pair, and so forth. There are no `Map.Entry` objects.

If you wish to iterate over the list using a `for` loop or the `iterator()` method, the `Map.Entry` objects are created on the fly. But the `forEach(BiConsmer<L, R> consumer)` method performs [internal iteration](https://wiki.c2.com/?InternalIterator), calling your consumer once for each pair. This is more efficient, because no `Map.Entry` objects are ever created.

In the following example, we create and populate a list, and iterate over it using internal and exterior iteration:

```
PairList<String, Integer> nameYears = PairList.of();
nameYears.add("Paul", 1942);
nameYears.add("John", 1940);
nameYears.add("Ringo", 1940);
nameYears.add("George", 1943);

// Exterior iteration
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair: nameYears) {
  println(pair.getKey() + " was born in " + pair.getValue());
}

// Internal iteration
nameYears.forEach((name, year) -> {
    println(name + " was born in " + year);
  });
```

There's also an immutable version, as follows:

```
interface ImmutablePairList<L, R> extends PairList<L, R> {
  static <L, R> ImmutablePairList<L, R> copyOf(Iterable<Map.Entry<L, R> iterable);
  static <L, R> ImmutablePairList<L, R> of(); // empty immutable list
  static <L, R> ImmutablePairList<L, R> of(L l, R r, Object ... rest); // list with 1 or more pairs
}
```

Because it never needs to be resized,`ImmutablePairList` uses an even more efficient backing store than a mutable `PairList`: an `Object[]` of size *2 * n* holds the pairs.

You can find the implementation in my Morel project: [interface PairList](https://github.com/hydromatic/morel/blob/main/src/main/java/net/hydromatic/morel/util/PairList.java#L46); feel free to copy it into your own code.