# Java Vector of Int Pair

Tags: java, eclipse, vector, integer

I want to have a vector of integer pairs in Java so I can store Cartesian coordinates in each cell. So it would look like :

```
|2,3|4,5|5,6|6,7|
```

Each cell of the vector has 2 ints. I tried doing this:

```
Vector<pair<Integer,Integer>> test = new Vector<pair<Integer,Integer>>();
```

But java could not resolve the word pair (even when I did ctrl+shift+O in eclipse to import all relevant libraries). Then I tried this:

```
Vector<pair<int,int>> test= new Vector<pair<int,int>>();
```

But it doesn't like the keyword `int` for some reason. Any ideas on how to make a vector of int pairs in Java?

Comment: Well where did you expect the `pair` type to come from? Also note that you can't use primitive types in Java generics, which is why `pair<int, int>` won't work.

Comment: That's impossible using just Generics! Congratulations, you hit the Erasure bound.7

Comment: Try to read this question:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777622/creating-a-list-of-pairs-in-java>

Comment: Please don't rely on Vector anymore. This class is from a long time past. Use an ArrayList or similar.

Comment: It looks an awful lot like you're just translating C++ STL code directly into Java. Java collections are not the same as STL containers, and Java genetics don't work the same as C++ templates, despite the surface similarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use e.g. `java.awt.Point` for this.

It has 2 int coordinates, just what you need.

`new Vector<java.awt.Point>`

Also, as others noted already, in fact you should use

`new ArrayList<java.awt.Point>`

and not use `Vector`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "pair" in Java.
But you can implement it yourself, like suggested here: [Creating a list of pairs in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777622/creating-a-list-of-pairs-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and since using `$ Pair<Integer, Integer>` was not a good option for me, I created a small class like

```
class TestPair{
    int i;
    int j;
}
```

And then I just normally used the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<TestPair> testArr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Min requirement** - Java 8 (As till Java 7 Pair class didn't exist).

JavaFX 2.2 has the [***javafx.util.Pair***](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class which can be used to store a pair.

First import the JavaFX as 
`import javafx.util.Pair;`

For example:

`Pair p1 = new Pair(1,7);
Pair p2 = new Pair(2,6);
Pair p3 = new Pair(1,7);
System.out.println(p1.equals(p3) + “and” + p2.equals(p3));`

OUTPUT :
`true and false`

This way you can use similar methods like getKey() and getValue() etc. Check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) for more methods and example code snippets.