# How to parse a string when compared to another string?

Tags: java, string, parsing, compare, match

In Java, I want to extract the differences from one comma-separated string when compared to another.

e.g

The string I want to extract the differences from: **1,hello,fire,dog,green**

The string I am comparing with                   : **1,hello,water,dog,yellow**

So the result of the function would give me a arraylist of [**3,fire**] and[**5,green**] as those items are different than the items in the second string, which are 'water' and 'yellow'. The numbers are the index positions of each item detected to be a difference. The other items match and are not considered.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java, sorry forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just loop through by splitting the strings.

`public static List<String> compareStrings(String str1, String str2) {
    String[] arrStr1 = str1.split(",");
    String[] arrStr2 = str2.split(",");
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int index = 0; index < arrStr1.length; ++index) {
        if (!arrStr1[index].equals(arrStr2[index])) {
            strList.add("[" + index + "," + arrStr1[index] + "]");
        }
    }
    return strList;
}`

Beaware of index out of bounds exception..!!

Comment: Wow, that is pretty simple, not sure how i didn't think of it. Thanks for your help. Ill use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create your own Pair class (based on [Creating a list of pairs in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777622/creating-a-list-of-pairs-in-java)), doesn't have to be template.

Then Do something like this:

Split the two strings:

```
List<String> toCompareSplit= Arrays.asList(toCompare.split(","));
List<String> compareWithSplit= Arrays.asList(compareWith.split(","));
```

Iterate the lists:

```
List<Pair> diffList= new ArrayList<Pair>(); 
for (int i= 0; i < toCompareSplit.size; i++){
    if (!toCompareSplit.get(i).equals(compareWithSplit.get(i))){
        Pair pair= new Pair(i+1, toCompareSplit.get(i));
        diffList.add(pair);
    }
}
```

If the lists aren't in the same size you can run to the end of the shortest one etc.

Comment: This way also seems to be similar to the marked answer, thanks for the suggestion.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var left = "1,hello,fire,dog,green";
var right = "1,hello,water,dog,yellow";
var result = left.Split(',').Zip(right.Split(','), Tuple.Create).Where(x => x.Item1 != x.Item2).ToArray();
```

Using C#, this will return an array of tuples of the different elements. Sorry I don't have a compiler to hand so may be some small syntax errors in there.

Comment: okay, I see you're using Java - my answer is not going to be of much use!