# Correct Type-Casting (or any other method) for a Java Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, casting

In this question [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java), there is this sample code that I will use in my code

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Pair) {
       Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
          return 
             ((  this.first == otherPair.first ||
                    ( this.first != null && otherPair.first != null &&
                      this.first.equals(otherPair.first))) &&
              (      this.second == otherPair.second ||
                     ( this.second != null && otherPair.second != null &&
                     this.second.equals(otherPair.second))) );
     }

     return false;
}
```

Eclipse warns me in the line "Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;" that the "Pair is a raw type. References to generic type Pair should be parameterized". I tried rewriting it to "Pair<A, B> otherPair = (Pair<A, B>) other;" but the warning is still there. How can I properly type-cast **other** so that no warnings will occur? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try also parameterizing the reference in the `instanceof` check?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>)other;
```

Since equals takes an Object, you won't have any trouble.  The type parameters are inconsequential in this particular code.