# Didn't Java once have a Pair class?

Tags: java

Am I remembering incorrectly, or did Java, once upon a time, provide a Pair class as part of its API?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in early versions one of the base classes -- Hashtable or some such -- had a non-public helper class that was a Pair (this was before inner classes).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There is no Pair in the standard framework, but the Apache Commons Lang, which comes quite close to “standard”, has a [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).

```
new MutablePair<>(1, "xxx");
new ImmutablePair<>(1, "xxx");
```

Comment: Pair<String, String> pair =  new ImmutablePair<String, String>(key, value);

Comment: If you happen to be developing for Android.. it has `Pair` also

Comment: Or even simpler: Pair<String, String> pair = Pair.of(key, value);

Comment: Have a look @gavenkoa's answer below. `java.util.Map.Entry` may be a simple solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the Pair implementation of android is immutable.

Comment: This answer is incomplete(and wrong) but unfortunately ranked highest as of seen today. Till JDK 10(and from Javafx 2.0) it had Pair class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/util/Pair.html. But it was in javafx.util package Not java.util which got many confused. With JDK 11, JavaFX being noncore module got separated from JDK so one cannot find(and yes surprised) Pair class after that. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3305073/removed-from-jdk-11-javafx-11-arrives-as-a-standalone-module.html

Answer (score 82):

## `Map.Entry`

Java 1.6 and upper have two implementation of [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface pairing a key with a value:

- [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)
- [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

[image: UML diagram of SimpleEntry & SimpleImmutableEntry classes inheriting from Map.Entry interface]

For example

```
Map.Entry < Month, Boolean > pair = 
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry <>( 
        Month.AUGUST , 
        Boolean.TRUE 
    )
;
```

> pair.toString(): AUGUST=true

I use it when need to store pairs (like size and object collection).

This piece from my production code:

```
public Map<L1Risk, Map.Entry<int[], Map<L2Risk, Map.Entry<int[], Map<L3Risk, List<Event>>>>>>
        getEventTable(RiskClassifier classifier) {
    Map<L1Risk, Map.Entry<int[], Map<L2Risk, Map.Entry<int[], Map<L3Risk, List<Event>>>>>> l1s = new HashMap<>();
    Map<L2Risk, Map.Entry<int[], Map<L3Risk, List<Event>>>> l2s = new HashMap<>();
    Map<L3Risk, List<Event>> l3s = new HashMap<>();
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    map.put(l3s, events);
    map.put(l2s, new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(l3Size, l3s));
    map.put(l1s, new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(l2Size, l2s));
}
```

Code looks complicated but instead of **Map.Entry** you limited to array of object (with size 2) and lose type checks...

Answer (score 38):

A Pair class :

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private final K element0;
    private final V element1;

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> createPair(K element0, V element1) {
        return new Pair<K, V>(element0, element1);
    }

    public Pair(K element0, V element1) {
        this.element0 = element0;
        this.element1 = element1;
    }

    public K getElement0() {
        return element0;
    }

    public V getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

}
```

usage :

```
Pair<Integer, String> pair = Pair.createPair(1, "test");
pair.getElement0();
pair.getElement1();
```

Immutable, only a pair !

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure why I thought Java had a Pair class, but I could have sworn it did at one point in its history.  I must be confusing it with another language.

Comment: If you've worked on Android projects (java based) then you've probably used their [Pair Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)

Answer (score 19):

There are lots of implementation around here, but all the time something is missing , the Override of equal and hash method.

here is a more complete version of this class:

```
/**
 * Container to ease passing around a tuple of two objects. This object provides a sensible
 * implementation of equals(), returning true if equals() is true on each of the contained
 * objects.
 */
public class Pair<F, S> {
    public final F first;
    public final S second;

    /**
     * Constructor for a Pair.
     *
     * @param first the first object in the Pair
     * @param second the second object in the pair
     */
    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    /**
     * Checks the two objects for equality by delegating to their respective
     * {@link Object#equals(Object)} methods.
     *
     * @param o the {@link Pair} to which this one is to be checked for equality
     * @return true if the underlying objects of the Pair are both considered
     *         equal
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Pair)) {
            return false;
        }
        Pair<?, ?> p = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(p.first, first) && Objects.equals(p.second, second);
    }

    /**
     * Compute a hash code using the hash codes of the underlying objects
     *
     * @return a hashcode of the Pair
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (first == null ? 0 : first.hashCode()) ^ (second == null ? 0 : second.hashCode());
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating an appropriately typed pair.
     * @param a the first object in the Pair
     * @param b the second object in the pair
     * @return a Pair that is templatized with the types of a and b
     */
    public static <A, B> Pair <A, B> create(A a, B b) {
        return new Pair<A, B>(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a copy/paste from AOSP (why not to add credit or reference?). To make it a complete version, at least replace the Objects#equal convenience method with actual implementation.

Comment: Needs to change "return Objects.equal(p.first, first) && Objects.equal(p.second, second);" to "return Objects.equals(p.first, first) && Objects.equals(p.second, second);"

Answer (score 17):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) should help.

To sum it up: a generic `Pair` class doesn't have any special semantics and you could as well need a `Tripplet` class etc. The developers of Java thus didn't include a generic `Pair` but suggest to write special classes (which isn't that hard) like `Point(x,y)`, `Range(start, end)` or `Map.Entry(key, value)`.

Answer (score 13):

No, but it's been [requested many times](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/03/31/do-we-want-a-java-util-pair/).

Answer (score 6):

No but JavaFX has it.

Cf. [Stack Overflow: Java Pair class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801088/2792078)

Answer (score 5):

Many 3rd party libraries have their versions of Pair, but Java has never had such a class. The closest is the inner interface java.util.Map.Entry, which exposes an immutable key property and a possibly mutable value property.

Answer (score 3):

It does seem odd. I found this thread, also thinking I'd seen one in the past, but couldn't find it in Javadoc.

I can see the Java developers' point about using specialised classes, and that the presence of a generic Pair class could cause developers to be lazy (perish the thought!)

However, in my experience, there are undoubtedly times when the thing you're modelling really is just a pair of things and coming up with a meaningful name for the relationship between the two halves of the pair, is actually more painful than just getting on with it. So instead, we're left to create a 'bespoke' class of practically boiler-plate code - probably called 'Pair'.

This could be a slippery slope, but a Pair and a Triplet class would cover a very large proportion of the use-cases.

Comment: Yup. I'm tired of creating my own every time

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pair (not supposedly key-value pair) just to hold two generic data together neither of the solutions above really handy since first (or so called Key) cannot be changed (neither in Apache Commons Lang's Pair nor in AbstractMap.SimpleEntry). They have thier own reasons, but still you may need to be able to change both of the components. Here is a Pair class in which both elements can be set

```
public class Pair<First, Second> {
    private First first;
    private Second second;

    public Pair(First first, Second second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public void setFirst(First first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void setSecond(Second second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public First getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public Second getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void set(First first, Second second) {
        setFirst(first);
        setSecond(second);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Pair pair = (Pair) o;

        if (first != null ? !first.equals(pair.first) : pair.first != null) return false;
        if (second != null ? !second.equals(pair.second) : pair.second != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = first != null ? first.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (second != null ? second.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For immutable, how about [`AbstratMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)?

Comment: problem with collection pairs is that, collections such as hashmap uses key for inserting and getting the vaue, you cannot change the key. if you want a pair, with a key and value, both changeable then you cant use AbstratMap.SimpleImmutableEntry, as i mentioned in the solution.

Comment: @hevi Maybe you encountered those inconveniences by using new Pair<>() instead of new MutablePair<>() or new ImmutablePair<>(). Pair<Boolean, Boolean> is not an issue.