# Store String+Integer pair in dynamic array?

Tags: java

I need to store few data pairs in array. Maybe few dozens. I only need to append, no need to delete, no need to search. Then I will access by index. Each pair is String value and Integer value. Java provides so many way to do this, which is the common practice for something like that? Two arrays? A class in an array?

I know how to do this in JavaScript:

```
var data = []
data.push(['Some name', 100])

//somewhere else
data.push(['Other name', 200])
```

but I need a solution for Java

Thank you.

Comment: java or javascript? :)

Comment: Do you *really* need an array rather than a list? I'd just create a class to encapsulate that pair of presumably-related values, and then create a list of that type, e.g. `List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();`

Comment: Java indeed. I use JavaScript as example because I know how to do it in JavaScript and have do not know what is the way in Java.

Comment: Creating an object with an attribute of a String and an Integer, at least for me, is the most convenient especially when it comes to maintainability.

Comment: you know Map ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html,  which you can use hashMap, multimap as you want

Comment: Sorry, I used the word "array" because in Russia we used to call anything that has 2+ items an "array". Actually if that's a list or a map or whatever else is ok. Anything that I can access by integer ID and can add dynamycally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you can create Pair class (or use implementations from apache commons) to store two elements in List.

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("Some name", 100));
```

See [Generic pair class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044923/generic-pair-class) and [Java Pair<T,N> class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316571/java-pairt-n-class-implementation) to see how you can implement Pair class.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends, but in general I think it is better to create an object and use a list of it:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String myString;
    private Integer myInt;
    // getters setters
}
```

And use:

```
List<MyObject> = new ArrayList<>();
```

(you can also use [Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) instead)

If the strings (or ints) are unique, you can use Map, but it is harder to get the insert index.

Another option is just two lists, one for Strings, one for Integers, and use same index in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

I go by using POJO as suggested above for this as this helps to define getter and setter for all the attributes of POJO, compare the objects by overriding equals and hashCode methods. By using getter and setter you know what is stored in what field and comparison can provide you sorting of objects as per your requirements. So this approach is cleaner and extensible for accommodating new requirements too. Also as you are putting data with sequential key so each instance of Pojo can be put in List (if required in sorted order.