# Is there a basic id / value object in Java?

Tags: java

I've created an "Attribut" class which is just a wrapper for a key/value single item. I know that Maps and HashMaps are designed for lists of this kind of items so I feel like i reinvented the wheel...
Is there some Class which fulfill this purpose ?

Regards

( My code to be clear about what i'm looking for )

```
public class Attribut {
    private int id;
    private String value;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't clarify anything. if what you want is to get `value` by id, then you're correct, `Map` would be the right way to go

Comment: Why you don't want to use Map<Integer,String>?

Comment: you are looking for a class which fulfills this purpose, And HashMap is a Class !! so whats really the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303539/didnt-java-once-have-a-pair-class

Comment: @Thilo : Yes, this is a duplicate but I didn't find those in my search, thank you for pointing these out.

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan, I don't want to use Map because I want a single pair, not a list of pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). There is also a [SimpleImmutableEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html).

However, I believe that it is not wrong designing your own type. There is a plethora of examples in the JDK itself where something like this (tuple) has been done:

- [java.awt.Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html)
- [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

I believe that it's a good thing, since you're code is more easily readable and you gain additional type safety.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse `Map.Entry<K, V>`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

In your case it'd be `Map.Entry<Integer, String>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's just an interface.

Comment: But there are two implementations SimpleEntry and SimpleImmutableEntry since JDK6.

Comment: @Thilo: That's cool! I hadn't realized that those had been made public.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap !

example :

```
    Map<Integer,String> attribut = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    attribut.put(1, "hi");
    String value = attribut.get(1);
```

you can iterate :

```
    for (Integer key : attribut.keySet()) {
        value = attribut.get(key);
    }
```

**EDIT :**

OK, just for a Pair !

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private final K element0;
    private final V element1;

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> createPair(K key, V value) {
        return new Pair<K, V>(key, value);
    }

    public Pair(K element0, V element1) {
        this.element0 = element0;
        this.element1 = element1;
    }

    public K getElement0() {
        return element0;
    }

    public V getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

}
```

usage :

```
    Pair<Integer, String> pair = Pair.createPair(1, "test");
    pair.getElement0();
    pair.getElement1();
```

Immutable, only a pair !

Comment: Why create an entire Map just to hold a pair of values?

Comment: That seems ok but as I just needed an int / string pair, I'll stay with my custom class.
Good generic code though :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not "reinventing the wheel", you just specifying your requirements. You want a class that constitutes a **mutable int/String pair**, and so your code is OK.

Your problem is that Java syntax is overly verbose. It would be nice to simply define it as something like

class IdValuePair(id: int, value: String)

but that's something for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Collections.singletonMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K, V)).