# How to implement Pair class in Java like in C++

Tags: java, c++, class, std-pair

How to realize class pair in Java like in C++, for using like in C++?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303539/didnt-java-once-have-a-pair-class

Comment: In most cases, it's a better idea to either a) use a class which describes the two fields, not just "left" and "right" or b) avoid needing such a class in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did it I did something similar to the `Map.Entry<K, V>` interface from the standard library. You should probably override `Object.equals(Object)` and `Object.hashCode()` so that two pairs where the key and value are logically equal to each other are logically equal and hash the same - see item 9 of Bloch's Effective Java for some pointers on how to do good implementations.

Here's what I did:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //same convention as AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
    return key + "=" + value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) return true;
    if(!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;

    Object otherKey = ((Pair<?, ?>)o).getKey();
    Object otherValue = ((Pair<?, ?>)o).getValue();
    return (key == null ? otherKey == null : key.equals(otherKey))
            && (value == null ? otherValue == null
                    : value.equals(otherValue));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 17 + 55555 * (key == null ? 72 : key.hashCode())
            + 232323 * (value == null ? 73 : value.hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Pair<F,S> {
    private F first;
    private S second;

    public Pair(F first, S second) { 
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public F getFirst() { return first }
    public S getSecond() { return second }
}
```

Comment: The C++ pair template allows a different type for the first and second elements

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to include the right header

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::makepair;
using std::pair;

void foo()
{
    string hello("Hello");
    float  value(42);

    auto p = makepair(hello, value); // or: pair<string, float> = ...
}
```

Comment: How does this work in Java?