# Subtract number from next number in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array that holds two doubles. I need to subtract number b from number a.

e.g. 30(number a) - 10(number b)

How do I iterate through my ArrayList and subtract these two numbers? I am not sure if I would need to iterate backwards or forwards.

My code so far. Does not produce the correct result, I am aware d - d would return 0 but I am unsure what to do here:

```
for (double d = numbersEnteredArrayList.size() - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
    equals = d - d;
    System.out.println(equals);
}
```

Comment: How is this ArrayList defined?

Comment: By the way, you may want to consider using a `Pair` class rather than an ArrayList as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5303539/642706).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using an array to store two numbers, but if you just need to subtract them you can access them directly.

```
double diff = numbersEnteredArrayList.get(1) - numbersEnteredArrayList.get(0);
```

Comment: I am building a calculator that takes multiple values, so the arraylist could have many. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @JamesB What should the result be if there are more than 2 values?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array in either direction.

Are you trying to output the difference of every sequential pair? If the array was `[6 4 2 7]` and you want to calculate and display `2 2 -5` (6-4)(4-2)(2-7) then just have the for loop start at 0, go until ArrayList.size()-1 and compute `numbersEnteredArrayList.get(d) - numbersEnteredArrayList.get(d+1)`

Answer (score -1):

You can keep track of the first value in the array using an `int` variable then keep subtracting from it as you iterate through the array (of course you would skip the first index).