# What are hashcode and equals in entry class in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I can see static Entry class in Hashmap in java have Equals and Hashcode methods.What is the purpose of these methods.put,get methods we use object hashcode and equals methods....

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    final int hash;

    /**
     * Creates new entry.
     */
    Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
        key = k;
        hash = h;
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
            return false;
        Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)o;
        Object k1 = getKey();
        Object k2 = e.getKey();
        if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
            Object v1 = getValue();
            Object v2 = e.getValue();
            if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public final int hashCode() {
        return (key==null   ? 0 : key.hashCode()) ^
               (value==null ? 0 : value.hashCode());
    }

    public final String toString() {
        return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
    }
```

Comment: It is Java hashmap class

Answer (score 1):

`Map.Entry` is a representation of a key-value pair, in a map. All of this methods can be used for comparing key-value pairs, not for comparing key-objects.

Answer (score 1):

`Entry`es are objects too, it's entirely possible to compare them for equality or to use them as keys in a map.

In addition, they are sometimes used as a poor man's `Pair` class: [Didn't Java once have a Pair class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303539/didnt-java-once-have-a-pair-class), https://www.baeldung.com/java-pairs, https://www.techiedelight.com/five-alternatives-pair-class-java/ and for this use you really want these implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`.