# Why Pair.getKey() and Pair.getValue() is throwing an error?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have set up a maven project. I am running it in Eclipse IDE but it throws an error:

I have already tried mvn clean and mvn eclipse: eclipse from scratch.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.amazon.mws.finances._2015_05_01.model.ShipmentEvent;
import com.amazon.mws.finances._2015_05_01.model.ShipmentItem;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair;
public Map<String, BigDecimal> getRefundEventFinancialSummary(ShipmentEvent shipmentEvent) {
Map<String, BigDecimal> chargeMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<ShipmentItem> refundItemsList = shipmentEvent.getShipmentItemAdjustmentList();
            List<Pair<String, BigDecimal>> accountedCostsList = refundItemsList.stream().map(this::getAccountedCosts)
                    .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (Pair<String, BigDecimal> pair : accountedCostsList) {
                String keyString = pair.getKey();
                if (chargeMap.containsKey(keyString)) {
                    chargeMap.replace(keyString, chargeMap.get(keyString).add(pair.getValue()));
                } else {
                    chargeMap.put(keyString, pair.getValue());
                }
            }
            return chargeMap;
          }
```

I don't see any issue with the logic but it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method getKey() is undefined for the type Pair<String,BigDecimal>
The method getValue() is undefined for the type Pair<String,BigDecimal>
The method getValue() is undefined for the type Pair<String,BigDecimal>
```

Please help me what could be the possible issue? Is it an eclipse problem?

**Edit:** Added the import statements.

Comment: Can you share your imports statements?

Comment: Try using Map.entryset() for iterating the maps

Comment: Why are you using `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair`? That is an internal class (i.e. private API) and you should not be using it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303539/didnt-java-once-have-a-pair-class for alternative Pair implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `import javafx.util.Pair` and the problem got solved. Thanks, everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Pair class which you are using doesn't have these methods. Try opening the Pair class in your eclipse(using java decompiler plugin).
If you are using `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair` class, you need to use `pair.fst` and `pair.snd`.
Changed code:

```
for (Pair<String, BigDecimal> pair : accountedCostsList) {
            String keyString = pair.fst;
            if (chargeMap.containsKey(keyString)) {
                chargeMap.replace(keyString, chargeMap.get(keyString).add(pair.snd));
            } else {
                chargeMap.put(keyString, pair.snd);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, You guessed it right. I'm using com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair but adding import pair.fst; and import pair.snd; didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Use `pair.fst` instead of using `pair.getKey()`. You don't need to add anything in your import statements. Check updated answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Katya047 Can you accept the answer, if this solves your issue?