# Using Parallel array Show highest sales value, and the month in which it occurred

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-arrays

I'm trying to display in the Message dialog on the `JOptionPane` the highest number of sales from my array of sales.

And I also want to show in which month they happened, but I am failing to find a way to display the month.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] CarSales= {1234,2343,1456,4567,8768,2346,9876,4987,7592,9658,7851,2538};
    
    String [] Months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June"
        ,"July ","August","September","October","November","December" };
    
    int HighNum = CarSales[0];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < CarSales.length; i++)
    {
        if(CarSales[i] > HighNum)
        {
            HighNum = CarSales[i];
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The highest car sales value is :"+HighNum +
        "-which happened in the month of");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use the Power of Objects

Avoid using parallel arrays in Java. It brings unnecessary complexity, makes the code brittle and less maintainable.

Your code doesn't automatically become object-oriented just because of the fact that you're using an object-oriented language.

Objects provide you an easy way of structuring your data and organizing the code (if you need to implement some functionality related, to a particular data you know where it should go - its plane is in the class representing the data).

So, to begin with, I advise you to implement a class, let's call it `CarSale`:

```
public static class CarSale {
    private Month month;
    private int amount;
    
    // getters, constructor, etc
}
```

Or, if you don't need it to be mutable, it can be implemented as a [Java 16 `record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html). In a nutshell, `record` is a specialized form of class, instances of which are meant to be transparent carriers of data (*you can not change their properties after instantiation*).

One of the greatest things about records is their concise syntax. The line below is an equivalent of the fully fledged class with getters, constructor, `equals/hashCode` and `toString` (all these would be generated for you by the compiler):

```
public record CarSale(Month month, int amount) {}
```

## java.time.Month

You've probably noticed that in the code above, property `month` is not a `String`. It's a standard enum [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) that resides in `java.time` package.

When you have a property that might have a limited set of values, `enum` is always preferred choice because contrary to a plain String, `enum` guards you from making typo and also enums have an extensive language support. So you don't need this array filled with moth-names.

That's how your code might look like:

```
CarSale[] carSales = {
    new CarSale(Month.JANUARY, 1234),
    new CarSale(Month.FEBRUARY, 2343),
    new CarSale(Month.MARCH, 1456),
    // ... 
};
        
// you might want to check if carSales is not is empty before accessing its first element
        
CarSale best = carSales[0];
        
for (CarSale sale: carSales) {
    if (sale.getAmount() > best.getAmount()) best = sale;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "The highest car sales value is :" + best.getAmount() +
    " which happened in the month of " + best.getMonth());
```

#### Note

- Try to keep your code aligned with [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Only names of classes and interface should start with a capital letter.
- In case if you've heard from someone that usage of parallel arrays can improve memory consumption, then I would advise to examine this question dipper and take a look at questions like this [Why use parallel arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347338/why-use-parallel-arrays-in-java) In case of such tiny arrays the only thing are disadvantages of a fragile code.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions but i'll give you the simplest based on your structure.
Just declare one String variable and assign the value whenever you change the highest num.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] CarSales= {1234,2343,1456,4567,8768,2346,9876,4987,7592,9658,7851,2538};

    String [] Months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June"
            ,"July ","August","September","October","November","December" };

    int HighNum = CarSales[0];
    String month = Months[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < CarSales.length; i++)
    {
        if(CarSales[i] > HighNum)
        {
            HighNum = CarSales[i];
            month = Months[i];
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The highest car sales value is :"+HighNum +
            "-which happened in the month of " + month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep an index. Whenever you change the highest found, update the index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] CarSales= {1234,2343,1456,4567,8768,2346,
                     9876,4987,7592,9658,7851,2538};

    String [] Months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June"
            ,"July ","August","September","October","November","December" };

    int HighNum = CarSales[0];
    int highMonth = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < CarSales.length; i++)
    {
        if(CarSales[i] > HighNum)
        {
            HighNum = CarSales[i];
            highMonth = i;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
         (null,"The highest car sales value is :"+HighNum +
            "-which happened in the month of " + Months[highMonth]);
}
```