# Closest Point on a Map

Tags: java, algorithm, computational-geometry

I am making a program where you can click on a map to see a "close-up view" of the area around it, such as on Google Maps.

When a user clicks on the map, it gets the X and Y coordinate of where they clicked.

Let's assume that I have an array of booleans of where these close-up view pictures are:

```
public static boolean[][] view_set=new boolean[Map.width][Map.height];
//The array of where pictures are.  The map has a width of 3313, and a height of 3329.
```

The program searches through a folder, where images are named to where the X and Y coordinate of where it was taken on the map.  The folder contains the following images (and more, but I'll only list five):

```
2377,1881.jpg, 2384,1980.jpg, 2389,1923.jpg, 2425,1860.jpg, 2475,1900.jpg
```

This means that:

```
view_set[2377][1881]=true;
view_set[2384][1980]=true;
view_set[2389][1923]=true;
view_set[2425][1860]=true;
view_set[2475][1900]=true;
```

If a user clicks at the X and Y of, for example, 2377,1882, then I need the program to figure out which image is closest (the answer in this case would be 2377,1881).

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for the smallest euclidean distance point without actually iterating over all pictures, is that correct?

Comment: ...I'm intrigued to know how many values in `view_set` are set to `true`? Why not just keep a set of co-ordinates (`int` pairs) in a set?

Comment: I added more tags, to attract users who are familiar with this kind of problem.

Comment: Maybe instead of making a large array with millions of elements you could try making an array of your images along with their associated point. Your problem would then consist of searching through the image list, comparing distances and returning the image closest to the given point.

Comment: @badroit Approximately 350-500 when I gather all of the images.

Comment: I would agree with @badroit, keeping a set of int coordinates will *likely* be far more efficient.

Comment: @ty1824 Alright, so I'll do that.  I still have the issue of actually finding the closest image though, I believe.

Comment: @Runis: If you have a list of coordinates, you can just search through that list for the nearest. 500 iterations of simple distance calculations and a few if-statements should be within your performance budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the location the user clicked, you could search for the nearest image using a Dijkstra search. 
Basically you start searching in increasingly larger rectangles around the clicked location for images. Of course you only have to search the boundaries of these rectangles, since you've already searched the body. This algorithm should stop as soon as an image is found.

Pseudo code:

```
int size = 0
Point result = default
while(result == default)
   result = searchRectangleBoundary(size++, pointClicked)

function Point searchRectangleBoundary(int size, Point centre)
{
    point p = {centre.X - size, centre.Y - size}
    for i in 0 to and including size
    {
        if(view_set[p.X + i][p.Y]) return { p.X + i, p.Y}
        if(view_set[p.X][p.Y + i]) return { p.X, p.Y + i}
        if(view_set[p.X + i][p.Y + size]) return { p.X + i, p.Y + size}
        if(view_set[p.X + size][p.Y + i]) return { p.X + size, p.Y + i}
    }
    return default
}
```

Do note that I've left out range checking for brevity.

There is a slight problem, but depending on the application, it might not be a problem. It doesn't use euclidian distances, but the manhattan metric. So it doesn't necessarily find the closest image, but an image at most the square root of 2 times as far.

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop? default is not modify in the sub function?

Comment: woops. forgot to increment `size`. ty

Answer (score 3):

Your `boolean[][]` is not a good datastructure for this problem, at least if it is not really dense (e.g. normally a point with close-up view is available in the surrounding 3×3 or maybe 5×5 square).

You want a 2-D-map with nearest-neighbor search. A useful data structure for this goal is the *[QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)*. This is a tree of degree 4, used to represent spatial data. (I'm describing here the "Region QuadTree with point data".)

Basically, it divides a rectangle in four about equal size rectangles, and subdivides each of the rectangles further *if there is more than one point in it*.

So a node in your tree is one of these:

- a empty leaf node (corresponding to a rectangle without points in it)
- a leaf node containing exactly one point (corresponding to a rectangle with one point in it)
- a inner node with four child nodes (corresponding to a rectangle with more than one point in it)

(In implementations, we can replace empty leaf nodes with a null-pointer in its parent.)

To find a point (or "the node a point would be in"), we start at the root node, look if our point is north/south/east/west of the dividing point, and go to the corresponding child node. We continue this until we arrive at some leaf node.

- For adding a new point, we either wind up with an empty node - then we can put the new point here. If we end up at a node with already a point in it, create four child nodes (by splitting the rectangle) and add both points to the appropriate child node. (This might be the same, then repeat recursively.)
- For the nearest-neighbor search, we will either wind up with an empty node - then we back up one level, and look at the other child nodes of this  parent (comparing each distance). If we reach a child node with one point in it, we measure the distance of our search point to this point. If it is smaller than the distance to the edges or the node, we are done. Otherwise we will have to look at the points in the neighboring nodes, too, and compare the results here, taking the minimum. (We will have to look at at most four points, I think.)
- For removal, after finding a point, we make its node empty. If the parent node now contains only one point, we replace it by a one-point leaf node.

The search and adding/removing are in O(depth) time complexity, where the maximum depth is limited by *log((map length+width)/minimal distance of two points in your structure)*, and average depth is depending on the distribution of the points (e.g. the average distance to the next point), more or less.

Space needed is depending on number of points and average depth of the tree.

There are some variants of this data structure (for example splitting a node only when there are more than X points in it, or splitting not necessarily in the middle), to optimize the space usage and avoid too large depths of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Based on

- your comment that states you have 350-500 points of interest,
- your question that states you have a map width of 3313, and a height of 3329

  - my calculator which tells me that that represents ~11 million boolean values

...you're going about this the wrong way. @JBSnorro's answer is quite an elegant way of finding the needle (350 points) in the haystack (11 million points), but really, why create the haystack in the first place?

As per my comment on your question, why not just use a [`Pair<Integer,Integer>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) class to represent co-ordinates, store them in a set, and scan them? It's simpler, quicker, less memory consuming, and is *way* more scalable for larger maps (assuming the points of interest are sparse... which it seems is a sensible assumption given that they're points of interest).

..trust me, computing the Euclidean distance ~425 times beats wandering around an 11 million value `boolean[][]` looking for the 1 value in 25,950 that's of interest (esp. in a worst case analysis).

---

If you're really not thrilled with the idea of scanning ~425 values each time, then (i) you're more OCD than me (`:P`); (ii) you should check out [nearest neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if you are asking for this. If the user point is P1 {x1, y1} and you want to calculate its distance to P2 {x2,y2}, the distance is calculated using Pythagoras'Theorem

```
distance^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
```

If you only want to know the closest, you can avoid calculating the square root (the smaller the distance, the smaller the square too so it serves you the same).

Comment: I believe the OP knows that, he is looking for a way to efficiently **find** this point, not how to calculate euclidean distance for 2 points.

Comment: Hey, I answer to the question being asked. If he wants the answer to another question, maybe he can post that question.