# Create a Google Guava Cache using a complex key

Tags: caching, guava

I'm trying to create a Cache that has a "Pair" as its key, with that Pair class taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java/3646398#3646398) post.

I'm trying:

```
CacheLoader<Pair<String, String>, String> loader =
    new CacheLoader<Pair<String, String>, String>() {
       public String load(Pair<String, String> key) {
           return GetRatingIdentityByShortNameLoader(key.first, key.second);
       }
    };

_ratingIdCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .concurrencyLevel(a_conclevel.intValue())
    .maximumSize(a_maxsize.intValue())
    .expireAfterAccess(a_maxage.intValue(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(loader);
```

Which fails to compile in Eclipse (helios, java 1.6) with:

> The method build(CacheLoader) in the type
>   CacheBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   CacheLoader,String>(){})

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this? The objective that that I need to have a cache that stores an "ID" for which the "primary key" is "Rating Agency" + "Rating".

Guava 10.0.1

Comment: Hmmm, embarrassed.... My first question on StackOverFlow, and already I mess up.

I had this cache originally defined as `Cache<String, String>`, and when I change the CacheBuilder.build() to use a complex key, I had forgotten to update my cache declaration.

Seems to be working now, or at least it compiles.

Comment: Don't feel embarrassed. It happens to me all the time. I guess you used SO as your rubber duck: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging ;)

Comment: So is there anything left that needs to be answered? Or can the question be withdrawn?

Comment: Hi, no, no question to be answered anymore. Because I am a new StackOverflow user I couldn't post the answer myself immediately. Will do so now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this cache originally defined as Cache, and when I change the CacheBuilder.build() to use a complex key, I had forgotten to update my cache declaration.

So a simple change from:

```
Cache<String, String> _ratingAgencyId;
```

to

```
Cache<Pair<String, String>, String> _ratingAgencyId;
```

did the trick.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. You should accept this answer for clarity.