# Return two values from a java method

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

Let's say I have a method in java, which looks up a user in a database and returns their address and the team they are on.

I want to return both values from the method, and don't want to split the method in two because it involves a database call and splitting involves twice the number of calls.

Given typical concerns in a moderate to large software project, what's the best option?

```
whatGoesHere getUserInfo(String name) {
  // query the DB
}
```

I know the question smells of duplication with existing ones, but each other question had some element that made it different enough from this example that I thought it was worth asking again.

Comment: some suggestions... create a struct yourself / use something like key-value pair / pass pointer in parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have some options.
The most OOP it will be create a class to encapsulate those 2 properties, something like that

```
private class UserInfo {
  private Address address;
  private Team team;
}
```

Or if you want a simple solution you can return an array of objects:

```
Object[] getUserInfo(String name) {
  // query the DB
  return new Object[]{address,team};
}
```

Or if you want to expose this method to some library you can have some interface that it will consume those properties, something like this:

```
class APIClass{
  interface UserInfo{
    public Address getAddress();
    public Team getTeam();
  }

  UserInfo getUserInfo(String name) {
    // query the DB
    return new UserInfo(){
         public Address getAddress(){ return address; }
         public Team getTeam(){ return team; }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create a class just for this purpose, since it creates extra noise.  Also, the user's team and name aren't "logically bound" - should I create a different class to represent every combination of values I might want to return from a query?

Comment: If the caller knows what to expect back, you could put it in a Map<String, Object> where your keys would be Address and Team.  This depends heavily on the caller knowing which keys to look for though.

Comment: so, you have 2 options, the second solution that I showed you(the array one), or get a bit fancier returning a HashMap, as @Thomas had suggested .

Comment: I think `getUserInfo` of the API approach should return `UserInfo` not `Object[]`.

Comment: me too. Dont return an array. its a messy solution. Use the "UserInfo" class. you can even add values later without changing everything. And as Thomas already said... the caller knows what to expect. so a UserInfo class is ok.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Why is the same query returning both values if they aren't logically related?

Answer (score 0):

cant a map help , A MultivalueMap. Where the key is the user name and the 2 values are the adress and the team name. I am assuming both your Address and team are String variables, You can know more about Multivalue Map here

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html

http://apachecommonstipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2009/01/multi-value-map-values-are-list.html

Comment: How would I tell which is the user name and which is the address?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: You can do with just the normal Map. You can map a String to an Object. This is less flaky than `Object[]`, but still not as good as creating a class.

Comment: The first value is always the key.. which is your user name and teh values are address and team names. your map will look like <UserName1 -->,Address1,Team1> You can then easily do a iteration over teh values and get the address and team names

Answer (score 0):

First model your abstractions, relationships and multiplicity well (see an e.g. below). Then you can model tables accordingly. Once these two steps are performed you can either leverage [JPA](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/getting/started) that can be configured to load your object graph or you write JDBC code and create the graph your self by running a SQL query with proper SQL JOINs.

- A User has an Address
- A Team can have 1 or more Users (and can a User play for more teams?)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a String array with user name and group name in it . The method looks like :

```
public String[] getUserInfo(String name) {
    String[] result = new String[2];
    // query the DB
    ...
    result[0] = userName;
    result[1] = groupName;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this kind of issue is to create a custom object with as many attributes as the values you want to return.
If you can't create a new class for this, you can use a `Map<String, Object>`, but this approach is not type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I thought [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) had a generic [`Pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) class already, but I cannot find it. You can build your own using generics if you're on Java 1.5+.

```
public class Pair<X,Y>
{
    public final X first;
    public final Y second;

    public Pair(X first, Y second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Feel free to make the fields private and add getters. :) Using it is easy:

```
return new Pair<Address,Team>(address, team);
```

**Update**

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has [`Pair`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) for more options.

Comment: In java 8, we have built in Pair<k,v> class in javafx.util package.