# Is there any generic name value pair in java?

Tags: java, generics

Is there any generic name value pair kind of stuff in java? i need something like

`Queue<NameValuePair<String,String>>` to store queue of name value pair of string values.

Comment: Have you come across Hashtable ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

commons-lang provide a `Pair`.

see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

EDIT: updated url as it was broken

Comment: @EldhoseMBabu, don't forget to accept the answer if it completely suits your needs.

Comment: @Peerke thanks for the downvote, I assume you was not able to find the updated URL by yourself so I updated the answer. Cheers