# Unordered pair in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a Java *generic* class to represent unordered pairs of any type. Meanwhile I see two solutions:

- `HashSet` to store the pair elements
- a `Pair` class with overriden `hashCode` and `equals` (to make `Pair(a, b)` and `Pair(b, a)` equal).

Does it make sense? What would you suggest?

Comment: What is your reason to write a container of `unordered paris of any type`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov You can consider for example edges of unordered graph. `Edge(v1, v2)` equals to `Edge(v2, v1)`.

Comment: @JBNizet I am interested in _unordered_ pairs.

Comment: Huh, 4 years and no answer. Did you find anything?

Comment: @user1803551 Actually, no :( Just forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

In your place I would roll out my own class. As long as you are interested in sets of only two objects, using `HashMap`, `HashSet` (which, incidentally, uses a `HashMap` internally anyway) or any other class designed for sets of arbitrary [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is a waste of resources and adds unneeded complexity.

Just create your own class with proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations. Having a `contains()` operation, or even implementing parts of the `Set` interface, might also make sense.

One important note: make sure you *document* your class extensively - at least specify whether `equals()` performs an identity or an equality comparison for the contained objects, and what is the meaning of a `null` contained reference...